# Массовые асинхронные вызовы с ограничением на количество параллельных без семафора

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, async-await, .net-5

Вполне простая задача - есть N упорядоченных запросов, которые надо выполнить асинхронно с ограничением на количество одновременно выполняемых, и потом достать их из них так же N упорядоченных ответов.

В реальности это может быть работа с сетью или базой, когда запросов много, но не хочется устроить апокалипсис своему компу, сети или серверу. Поэтому вводится ограничение на количество одновременно активных асинхронных задач.

Лобовое решение выглядит очевидно.

```cs
public async Task<Tout[]> RunSemaphoreAsync<Tin, Tout>(IEnumerable<Tin> items, Func<Tin, Task<Tout>> func, int degree)
{
    using SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new(degree);
    return await Task.WhenAll(items.Select(async item => {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            return await func(item);
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }));
}
```

Пример использования:

Пусть это будет рабочая задача, которая что-то принимает, что-то делает и что-то отдает назад.

```cs
public async Task<int> RunJobAsync(int n)
{
    await Task.Yield(); 
    return n + 1;
}
```

И вот такой запуск для примера.

```cs
IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 100);
int[] result = await RunSemaphoreAsync(numbers, RunJobAsync, Environment.ProcessorCount * 2);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result));
```

Всё работает работает как часики, быстро и ожидаемо.

---

С тем что выше все отлично, но мне однажды, когда я в очередной раз читал про всякие реализации Producer/Consumer паттерна, пришла идея использовать воркеры вместо семафора. Собственно, почему нет.

Получился вот такой метод.

```cs
public async Task<Tout[]> RunWorkersAsync<Tin, Tout>(IEnumerable<Tin> items, Func<Tin, Task<Tout>> func, int degree)
{
    List<Task<Tout>> tasks = new();
    using (var source = items.GetEnumerator())
    {
        Task[] jobs = new Task[degree];
        for (int i = 0; i < degree; i++)
        {
            jobs[i] = ((Func<Task>)(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Task<Tout> task;
                    lock (source)
                    {
                        if (source.MoveNext())
                        {
                            task = func(source.Current);
                            tasks.Add(task);
                        }
                        else
                            break;
                    }
                    await task;
                }
            }))();
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(jobs);
    }
    return tasks.Select(t => t.Result).ToArray();
}
```

Работает точно так же красиво как и первый кандидат. Тогда что же лучше?

---

И решил я померять оверхед.
Я не мастер писать бенчмарки, но кого когда это останавливало? :)

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = BenchmarkRunner.Run<MyBenchmarks>();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class MyBenchmarks
{
    private readonly List<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 2000).ToList();
    private readonly int degree = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2;

    [Benchmark]
    public Task SemaphoreTest()
    {
        return RunSemaphoreAsync(numbers, RunJobAsync, degree);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public Task WorkersTest()
    {
        return RunWorkersAsync(numbers, RunJobAsync, degree);
    }

    public async Task<int> RunJobAsync(int n)
    {
        await Task.Yield(); 
        return n + 1;
    }

    public async Task<Tout[]> RunSemaphoreAsync<Tin, Tout>(IEnumerable<Tin> items, Func<Tin, Task<Tout>> func, int degree)
    {
        using SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new(degree);
        return await Task.WhenAll(items.Select(async item => {
            await semaphore.WaitAsync();
            try
            {
                return await func(item);
            }
            finally
            {
                semaphore.Release();
            }
        }));
    }

    public async Task<Tout[]> RunWorkersAsync<Tin, Tout>(IEnumerable<Tin> items, Func<Tin, Task<Tout>> func, int degree)
    {
        List<Task<Tout>> tasks = new();
        using (var source = items.GetEnumerator())
        {
            Task[] jobs = new Task[degree];
            for (int i = 0; i < degree; i++)
            {
                jobs[i] = ((Func<Task>)(async () =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Task<Tout> task;
                        lock (source)
                        {
                            if (source.MoveNext())
                            {
                                task = func(source.Current);
                                tasks.Add(task);
                            }
                            else
                                break;
                        }
                        await task;
                    }
                }))();
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(jobs);
        }
        return tasks.Select(t => t.Result).ToArray();
    }
}
```

И тут получаю интересный результат

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.0, OS=Windows 10.0.19043.1081 (21H1/May2021Update)
Intel Core i7-4700HQ CPU 2.40GHz (Haswell), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET SDK=5.0.301
  [Host]     : .NET 5.0.7 (5.0.721.25508), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET 5.0.7 (5.0.721.25508), X64 RyuJIT
```

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SemaphoreTest | 1,780.2 us | 4.23 us | 3.95 us | 140.6250 | 41.0156 | - | 519 KB |
| WorkersTest | 943.2 us | 18.37 us | 26.92 us | 74.2188 | 19.5313 | - | 262 KB |

Глаза отказываются в это верить. Почему метод с семафором просто вот так вот слился, а быть может кривой тест или кривая реализация? Рассудите пожалуйста.

*P.S. Я же не сразу побежал на SO, а первым делом поискал жалобы на медленный `SemaphoreSlim`...и не нашел, но нашел вот что: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/55262. Другими словами, светофорчик немного полечат в .NET 6.*

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127403/discussion-on-question-by-aepot-------).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Код для RunWorkersAsync и для RunSemaphoreAsync по разному распределяет работу между потоками.

В RunWorkersAsync в первоначальном потоке отрабатывает только первая операция цикла while каждого *worker-a*, после этого перебор происходит в несколько потоков, т.к. все после вызова await отрабатывает на потоках из пула. Больше никакой завязки на какой-то общий поток в коде нет.

В RunSemaphoreAsync же в первоначальном потоке для каждого *элемента* отрабатывает

```
items.Select(async item => {
        semaphore.WaitAsync(); // await и продолжение - на потоке из пула
```

Соответственно, в этом варианте основной поток становится узким местом. Обработчики не могут разгребать работу быстрее, чем этот поток ее создает.

Это можно решить принудительным yield прямо в начале цикла:

```
public async Task<Tout[]> RunSemaphoreAsync<Tin, Tout>(IEnumerable<Tin> items, Func<Tin, Task<Tout>> func, int degree)
{
    using SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new(degree);
    return await Task.WhenAll(items.Select(async item =>
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            return await func(item);
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }));
}
```

Результаты станут чуть лучше, но сам боттлнек в виде одного потока все равно не исчезнет.

Answer (score 4):

Я решил попробовать применить каналы - Channel. Код получился такой:

```
public async Task<Tout[]> RunChannelAsync<Tin, Tout>(IEnumerable<Tin> items, Func<Tin, Task<Tout>> func, int degree)
{
    var channel = Channel.CreateBounded<Task<Tout>>(degree);

    var writer = channel.Writer;
    var reader = channel.Reader;

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        foreach (Tin item in items)
            await writer.WriteAsync(func(item));

        writer.Complete();
    });

    var tasks = new List<Tout>();

    await foreach (Task<Tout> item in reader.ReadAllAsync())
        tasks.Add(await item);

    return tasks.ToArray();
}
```

Количество одновременно выполняемых задач задаётся в методе `CreateBounded`.

Производительность получилась средняя.
Причина фактически та же, что и с семафором: задачи создаёт один поток, как объяснил PashaPash.

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SemaphoreTest | 1,148.9 us | 15.50 us | 14.50 us | 156.2500 | 48.8281 | - | 527 KB |
| SemaphoreYieldTest | 1,154.4 us | 22.51 us | 40.59 us | 169.9219 | 68.3594 | - | 711 KB |
| WorkersTest | 763.3 us | 5.61 us | 5.25 us | 87.8906 | 27.3438 | - | 260 KB |
| ChannelTest | 991.8 us | 6.64 us | 6.21 us | 125.0000 | - | - | 246 KB |

Разве что мусора генерируется мало. Даже до первого поколения не доходит.

Ещё я бы хотел отметить, что вариант на семафорах с `await Task.Yield();` на моей машине работает как и без него, в пределах погрешности и даже хуже.

---

Основная причина, по которой я решил написать, такова. Тестируемые методы принимают `IEnumerable` - это хорошо, значения могут генерироваться или получаться откуда-либо на лету.
А вот результат возвращается сразу весь целиком, в виде массива. Таким образом, отчасти теряется асинхронность, т. к. получается блокировка на создании/получении этого массива.

Comment: Очень странно, что нет разницы между yield и семафором. У меня разница в 1,5-2 раза в лучщую сторону в пользу yield.

Comment: Если что я бенчмарки гонял на чистом x64. Без каких-либо контекстов синхронизации.

Comment: @aepot - Win10, x64, .net-5, console

Comment: прогнал у себя. Каналы в 2 раза медленнее воркеров, то есть еще хуже семафора получились. Быть может у меня меньше физических ядер (4), чем у вас, а оно вроде-как зависит. У меня `degree = 16`.

Comment: Последнюю проблему можно решить, используя IAsyncEnumerable, возвращая пачками работу, не придется дожидаться всей её работы целиком. На моей машине вышло чуть медленнее чем воркеры

Comment: @aepot - у меня слабый ноутбучный i3, 2 физических ядра, 4 логических.

Comment: @Vein - да, это напрашивается само собой. Однако, нам же нужно в любом случае дождаться материализации этих данных, чтобы выполнить тест. Так что, видимо, придётся признать, что текущие тесты правильно отражают оверхед разных способов.