# Реализация параллельных тасков, не используя Task.Run

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, asp.net-core, asp

Не могу понять, как получить много тасков в цикле для функции, чтобы потом вернуть Task.WhenAll. Надо что то использовать вместо Task.Run, т.к. он съедает N потоков.

```
  List<Task<Model>> models = new List<Task<Model>>();

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                foreach (var communityId in item.CommunityIds)
                {
                    models.Add(Task.Run(() => ToContentItem(item, addresses.TryGetValueOrDefault(item.Id), chats.TryGetValueOrDefault(item.Id), communities.TryGetValueOrDefault(communityId)))); 
                }
            }

            return await Task.WhenAll(models);
```

Чем можно заменить Task.Run?

Пытался сделать так:

```
      foreach (var communityId in item.CommunityIds)
                {
                    baseNewsContentItems.Add(new Task(() => {

                        ToContentItem(item, addresses.TryGetValueOrDefault(item.Id), chats.TryGetValueOrDefault(item.Id), communities.TryGetValueOrDefault(communityId))
                        });
                    ) ; 
                }
```

но код ругается, что не хватает ")", хотя вроде все есть

Comment: `он съедает N потоков` - и что в этом плохого? Немного не пойму чего вы хотите и зачем.

Comment: [Быть может это поможет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567).

Comment: если вы хотите сделать цикл параллельным, используйте `Task.Parallel`, в противном случае не вижу альтернативы потокам

Comment: `Task.Run, т.к. он съедает N потоков` Task.Run использует шедулер по умолчанию, а значит используется пул потоков, который ограничен. То есть потоков будет столько, сколько решит пул потоков, а он для этого и создан, чтобы такие вещи решать.

Comment: можно так `var models = items.SelectMany(i=>i.CommunityIds)`.AsParallel().Seelct(x=>ToContentItem(x,...)).ToList(); - по умолчанию тут потоков будет создано столько же, как и в вшем варианте. Но это можно ограничить настроками параллелизма, читайте про PLinq

Comment: `});` - вот тут `;` лишняя

Comment: `ToContentItem` - что делает этот метода, какова его реализация? Он загружает процессор или обращается к IO?

Comment: Аналогичные вопросы к методам `TryGetValueOrDefault`. / Если методы загружают процессор - то без потоков не обойтись. Если методы используют ввод-вывод - их следует переписать с использованием асинхронности.

Comment: Не используйте конструктор `new Task`, совсем, никогда, вообще.