# Работает ли lock внутри потоков, запущенных в semaphoreslim?

Tags: c#

часть кода в методе запускаемом в Thread ограждена lock(locker){для 1 потока}
без семафора потоки работают корректно.
в семафоре такое ощущение, что локер не работает
Если в семафоре не работает локер, то как ограничить часть кода только для 1го, если семафор запускать (5,5) например?

код запуска потоков

```
_pool = new SemaphoreSlim(5, 5);

await Task.Run(() => 
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
       {
          Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(CircleForPool));

          t.Start(null);
       }
});
```

код метода:

```
public void CircleForPool(object obj)
      {
          _pool.Wait();
          //некоторый код
          lock(Locker)
              {
                 //некоторый код
              }
          //некоторый код
          _pool.Release();
       }
```

так же замечено странное поведение в семафоре, кода, который не лочится дополнительно:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("keys.txt");
KeyApi = lines[new Random().Next(lines.Length)];
```

тут берётся случайное значение из файла, в котором около 200 строк, и на старте сразу 6 потоков из 10 (ограниченных семафором) берут один и тот же ключ

так же подобный код в локе (этот метод вызывается внутри потока):

```
public string TakeFolder(string domen)
        {
            
            string folder = "";
            lock (locker)
            {
                string[] profile = File.ReadAllLines("listprofile.txt");
                List<string> newprofile = new List<string>();
                int count = profile.Where(x => x.Contains(domen)).Count();
                int rndtake = new Random().Next(1, count + 1);
                int num = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < profile.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (profile[i].Contains(domen))
                    {
                        num += 1;
                    }
                    if (profile[i].Contains(domen) && folder == "")
                    {
                        folder = profile[i].Split(':')[1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newprofile.Add(profile[i]);
                    }
                }
                if (folder != "")
                {
                    File.WriteAllLines("listprofile.txt", newprofile.ToArray());
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                }
            }


            return folder;
        }
```

Comment: lock работает независимо от наличия семафора в коде. покажите код.

Comment: Локи работают везде, вопрос только в правильном использовании. Использовать потоки (Thread) на низком уровне - это неудобно и не эффективно. Чтобы вам помочь, надо знать задачу, которую вы решаете и видеть код, который не работает как надо. Так что вам нужно сделать? Зачем потоки? Зачем семафор? Кстати, вот [есть такой пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567).

Comment: добавил пример кода. при пошаговом выполнении, вижу что лок вроде работает, но когда запускаю в работу многопоток, то в дебаге вижу ошибку, которая возникает, если разные потоки запускается с одним и тем же значением, которое берётся в локе из файла с удалением, как будто лок не срабатывает

Comment: а как Locker объявлен? просто статическая переменная? тогда должно правильно работать.

Comment: да, как статик переменная. и без семафора всё работало безупречно, может в каком-то другом коде есть логика ошибочная, но решил перепроверить и спросить про семафор

Comment: покажите весь код, включая тот кусок, который работает неправильно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new Random()` использует текущее время в качестве начального seed. Поэтому когда вы вызываете `new Random()` одновременно вне лока - вы получаете один и тот же ключ. Используйте общий объект `Random` - положите его в поле или в статику, и оберните вызов `Next` в лок (с отдельным locker).

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Random__ctor

> In .NET Framework, the default seed value is derived from the system clock, which has finite resolution. As a result, different Random objects that are created in **close succession** by a call to the parameterless constructor have **identical default seed** values and, therefore, produce **identical sets of random numbers**. You can avoid this problem by using a single Random object to generate all random numbers.

В .NET Core будет работать без выноса в поле класса, там это починили на уровне фреймворка.

Comment: да, это исправило ситуацию. без семафора запускал потоки с промежутками времени и это не было заметно, а с семафором стало проблемой, на него и подумал. Спасибо!

Comment: @АрхиповВладимир не понимаю, зачем вообще использовать древний фреймворк для новой разработки. И зачем вам вообще `new Thread`, когда есть `Task.Run`. Если вас смущает асинхронный метод, а нужно просто запустить и забыть, то есть `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` - его и используйте для запуска потоков вместо `Thread`, если `Task.Run` не устраивает. А если уж взялись за `Thread` - важно понимать, чем `Background` поток отличается от обычного, внутри этого понимания закопан сюрприз в виде зависания всего приложения в системных задачах при выходе.

Comment: когда изучал многопоточность Thread был основным в понимании, так и пошло, таски даже не рассматривал, сейчас уже есть понимание тасков, но по привычке thread использую

Comment: @aepot - так же у таска нет abort() и если зависает из-за чужой библиотеки непонятно пока - что делать в таких случаях

Comment: @АрхиповВладимир `Thread.Abort()` является устаревшим и уже выпилен из дотнета. Вопрос надежного прибивания чужого кода очень сложный, и аборт не спасет. Попробуйте запустить поток с кодом `try { Thread.Sleep(int.MaxValue); } finally { while (true) { } }` этот код повесит поток намертво и вы не сможете его убить, никак, аборт не поможет. Единственный способ гарантированно убить поток - это запустить его в отдельном процессе и убить процесс средствами операционки. Не используйте `Abort()`, он не дает никаких гарантий.

Comment: @aepot, спасибо за совет с отдельным процессом, в текущей работе, это наверное будет лучшим решением