# Эффективность использования System.Threading.ThreadPool в C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность, threading

Как известно, для максимальной загрузки физических потоков и снижения количества различного рода узких мест в перфомансе приложения, вроде затраченного времени на создание потоков вручную, применяется пул программных потоков. В .net есть "стандартный" пул потоков:System.Threading.ThreadPool, который позволяет как запускать задачи через QueueUserWorkltem, утилизируя один из потоков пула целиком, так и использовать TPL поверх себя, что вкупе с async-await позволяет более эффективно использовать каждый отдельно взятый поток, снижая context switch и не блокируя его тогда, когда это не требуется.

Однако System.Threading.ThreadPool используется не только для пользовательских задач. Данный пул один для всех доменов внутри одного процесса и он может использоваться самим фреймворком для своих системных задач, а также всеми библиотеками, используемыми в рантайме(внутри себя они могут делать Task.Run, Task.Factory.StartNew и так далее).

В тоже время, разработчик может сделать свою реализацию пула потоков(или использовать прекрасный SmartThreadPool) и перенести пользовательские задачи на него, чтобы гарантированно не смешивать задачи друг с другом.

Вопрос 1: правильно ли я понимаю, что System.Threading.ThreadPool может использоваться кем угодно внутри одного процесса, что будет негативно сказываться на пользовательских задачах?

Вопрос 2: верно ли, что использование кастомного пула потоков(со своими параметрами приоритезации, количества самих потоков и пр. ) всегда эффективнее для пользовательских задач, независимо от того, как организована многопоточность(треды, таски)?

Вопрос 3: Когда лучше использовать кастомный пул потоков, а когда достаточно стандартного System.Threading.ThreadPool и как следствие Task.Run(e.t.c) ?

Comment: 2. Нет, не всегда. Потоки будут и в кастомном пуле, и в стандартном (если не ограничить их количество до нуля), в результате ОС будет вхолостую тратить время на их переключение. Ну и банально кастомный пул может быть плохо написан. Например, work stealing не реализован.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread Pool в его базовой реализации решает ровно одну проблему - запуск потока - это дороже, чем использование существующего. При этом на простое решение "запустить сразу много потоков" есть обратное ограничение - любой поток, даже не выполняющий код, требует достаточно много памяти.

Соответственно, у вызывающего кода есть ровно одно пожелание к пулу - поток из пула должен быть выдан как можно быстрее.

И с точки зрения пула, и с точки зрения вызывающего кода - потоки одинаковые. Нет никакой разницы, был ли поток раньше использован таском, тредом, или await-ом - после ухода в пул и выдачи обратно он ничем не будет отличатся от других потоков. Поэтому нет смысла делить задачи на "системные" и "пользовательские" - поток он и есть поток, главное чтобы пул выдал его быстро, а не тупил.

Поэтому какое-то кастомное управление потоками имеет смысл только в случае, если паттерн использования потоков в какой-то части приложения сильно отличается от просто "выполнить в фоне/параллельно". В этом случае вы можете сэкономить не просто на создании потоков, а еще и на выдаче их из пулла. Например:

- Распараллеливание обработки массива - Parallel.For - переиспользует потоки, а не просто закидывает в пулл обработку всех элементов по одному.
- [Producer/Consumer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/177221) с фиксированным/управляемым количеством Consumer-ов.
- Мультиплексирование запросов - использование выделенных потоков для работы с сетью и ответами/запросами, вместо парсинга каждого ответа в потоке из пулла (StackExchange.Redis)
- IO Completion Threads - отдельная категория потоков с стандартном пулле, которая занимается только тем, что перебрасывает результаты дисковых/сетевых вызовов обратно в пользовательские потоки.

Вот если у вас возникнет что-то такое специфическое, где просто "быстро получить поток из пулла" уже недостаточно - тогда да, отдельный пулл потоков (а скорее - ручное управление потоками) вам поможет. А если нет - то нет.

Это ответ на вопрос #3. А на первые два - просто "нет", по причинам, перечисленным выше :)