# Найти все ссылки в ссылках C#

Tags: c#, html, парсер

Сделал парсер который вытягивает код со страницы html , затем ищет все ссылки на странице, отсеял посторонние ресурсы , добавил ссылки в список, так же есть список посещенных ссылок ( то есть уже проверенных ссылок где были вытянутые ссылки )
Теперь мне надо зайди в список ссылок и по каждой ссылки перейти и проверить там вытянуть ссылки которых ещё нету , но затем на непосещенные ссылки надо будет зайти ещё раз
Как это всё устроить ? Один-два раза я могу вручную написать, но как сделать так чтобы оно обошло нужное количество раз , я же не знаю сколько там может раз заходить в ссылки в ссылках чтобы найти новые ссылки и когда и как остановить этот процесс?

```
   class webCrawler
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> list = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        List<string> visitedUrl = new List<string>();

        internal async Task startCrawler(string url)
        {
            await proccessCrawler(url, checkUrl); // здесь я list.Add
            visitedUrl.Add(url);

            foreach (var item in list.Keys.ToList()) // ??? здесь мой вопрос
            {
                    if (!visitedUrl.Contains(item))
                    {
                        visitedUrl.Add(item);
                        await proccessCrawler(item, item.Replace("https://", ""));
                        Console.WriteLine($"Added new {item}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Found repeat.");
                    }
            }
        }
    }

private async Task proccessCrawler(string url, string checkUrl)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
            var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

            HtmlNodeCollection nodes = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");

            foreach (var n in nodes)
            {
                string href = n.Attributes["href"].Value;
                try
                {
                    var absUrl = GetAbsoluteUrlString(url, href);
                    if (absUrl.Contains(checkUrl))
                    {
                        list.Add(absUrl, "");
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }

        private string GetAbsoluteUrlString(string baseUrl, string url)
        {
            var uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            if (!uri.IsAbsoluteUri)
                uri = new Uri(new Uri(baseUrl), uri);
            return uri.ToString();
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: необходим метод который может вызывать сам себя рекурсивно

Comment: `proccessCrawler` покажите, налицо непонимание, где надо `Task.Run`, а где не надо :). Здесь у вас явная IO-Bound операция, а вы ее почему-то в поток. Плюс конечно же потребуется либо рекурсия, либо стек в методе, который вы не показали.

Comment: @aepot Task Run не нужен здесь, была какае то проблема с потоком , пробовал разное и забыл убрать Task Run, сперва накидал лиж бы работало, а затем уже буду улучшать чтобы было всё правильно , а не всё сразу

Comment: `proccessCrawler` покажете?

Comment: @aepot добавил, использовал нугет пакеты HtmlAgilityPack и System.Net.Http;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Вам не нужно создавать `HttpClient` на каждый запрос, достаточно одного, во всяком случае для одного хоста, а еще он будет вести себя как браузер в плане кук.
- Вам необязательно читать ответ, если сервер вернул ошибку
- Не каждый ответ сервера - HTML страница
- Не каждая ссылка на странице - страница этого же сервера
- Не каждый сервер отвечает нормально, если не задан User-Agent
- Не каждый ответ от сервера - это ответ с того адреса, который вы запросили
- Чтобы сделать обход - нужна рекурсия
- Чтобы сделать обход быстрее, нужно параллелить запросы. Чтобы параллелить запросы, можно использовать коллекцию тасков ([примеры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567))
- Намудрили со ссылками
- Чтобы не ходить на одну и ту же ссылку дважды, нужно это проверять
- HTTP/2 быстрее, чем HTTP/1.1, архивирование ответов тоже ускоряет работу

В общем, вам тут очень много всего не хватает. Я решение представляю примерно так:

```
class Crawler : IDisposable
{
    private const int maxRequestCount = 10;
    private int _requestCount;

    private readonly string _host;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly HashSet<string> _set;

    public Crawler(string host)
    {
        _host = host;
        _set = new HashSet<string>();
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler() { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All };
        _client = new HttpClient(handler) { DefaultRequestVersion = HttpVersion.Version20 };
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36");
        _client.BaseAddress = new UriBuilder("https://", host).Uri;
    }

    public async Task<string[]> RunAsync(int depth)
    {
        _requestCount = 0;
        _set.Clear();
        Uri uri = new Uri("/", UriKind.Relative);
        _set.Add(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uri.ToString()));
        await ParsePage(uri, depth);
        return _set.ToArray();
    }

    private async Task ParsePage(Uri path, int depth)
    {
        if (Interlocked.Increment(ref _requestCount) > maxRequestCount)
            return;
        using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, path);
        using var response = await _client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode || response.Content == null || response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType != "text/html")
        {
            Console.WriteLine($">> Invalid response: {response.RequestMessage.RequestUri}, {(int)response.StatusCode} {response.ReasonPhrase} {response.Content?.Headers.ContentType.MediaType ?? "<no content>"}");
            return;
        }
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head/title")?.InnerText.Trim() ?? "<no title>");

        var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]").Select(node => node.Attributes["href"].Value).Where(link => link.Length > 0 && !link.StartsWith("#"));
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (string link in links)
        {
            try
            {
                var uri = new Uri(link, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                if (uri.IsAbsoluteUri && uri.Host != _host)
                {
                    // Console.WriteLine($">> External link ignored: {HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uri.ToString())}");
                    continue;
                }
                uri = new Uri(uri.IsAbsoluteUri ? uri.PathAndQuery : uri.ToString(), UriKind.Relative);
                lock (_set)
                {
                    if (!_set.Add(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uri.ToString())))
                    {
                        // Console.WriteLine($">> Page already visited: {HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uri.ToString())}");
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                if (depth > 0)
                    tasks.Add(ParsePage(uri, depth - 1));
            }
            catch (UriFormatException) { }
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _client.Dispose();
    }
}
```

То есть не уходя на сторонний хост, просто собирать ссылки, и сохранять все как релативные, для поддержания стандарта. Без лишних запросов.

Этот код - просто набросок, сюда я бы еще [вкрутил семафор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567) и более детальный анализ того, что происходит. Еще можно добавить черный список ссылок, которые точно не нужны.

Запускаю

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    using var crawler = new Crawler("ru.stackoverflow.com");
    var links = await crawler.RunAsync(2);
    Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 80));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, links));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Stack Overflow на русском
Тур - Stack Overflow на русском
Войти - Stack Overflow на русском
Войти - Stack Overflow на русском
Справка - Stack Overflow на русском
Регистрация - Stack Overflow на русском
Новые вопросы - Stack Overflow на русском
Регистрация - Stack Overflow на русском
Регистрация - Stack Overflow на русском
Метки - Stack Overflow на русском
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/
/tour
/help
/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
/users/signup?ssrc=head&returnurl=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
/users/signup?ssrc=site_switcher&amp;returnurl=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
/users/login?ssrc=site_switcher&amp;returnurl=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
/users/signup?ssrc=hero&amp;returnurl=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
/questions
/tags
/users
/unanswered
/questions/ask
/?tags=javascript
/?tags=php
/?tags=python
/?tags=java
/?tags=c#
/?tags=html
/?tags=android
/?tags=c++
/?tags=css
/?tags=jquery
?tab=interesting
?tab=bounties
?tab=hot
?tab=week
?tab=month
/questions/1378505/Как-проверить-на-отсутствие-ключа-если-его-нет-то-создать-ключ-и-присвоить-знач
/questions/tagged/javascript
/users/176262/igor
/questions/1378505/Как-проверить-на-отсутствие-ключа-если-его-нет-то-создать-ключ-и-присвоить-знач?lastactivity
/questions/1378511/macos-big-sur-не-работает-compser
/questions/tagged/macos
/questions/tagged/composer
/users/23971/diefair
/questions/1378502/nginx-возвращает-500-internal-server-error
/questions/tagged/nginx
/questions/tagged/веб-сервер
/users/426765/sirius-mklain
/questions/1377846/Нет-связей-между-моделями-БД-во-время-выполнения-asp-net-5-mvc
/questions/tagged/c#
/questions/tagged/asp.net-core
/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-mvc
/users/483377/cyberninja2007
/questions/1377846/Нет-связей-между-моделями-БД-во-время-выполнения-asp-net-5-mvc?lastactivity
/questions/1378510/Выборка-наименьших-ближайших-дат-в-df2-из-значений-в-df1
/questions/tagged/python
/questions/tagged/pandas
/questions/tagged/datetime
/users/483933/user483933
/questions/1378500/Что-нужно-дописать-чтобы-программа-правильно-проверяла-правильность-скобок-На
/questions/tagged/функции
/users/254172/passant
/questions/1378500/Что-нужно-дописать-чтобы-программа-правильно-проверяла-правильность-скобок-На?lastactivity
/questions/1378508/Не-осуществляется-метод-destroy-ruby-on-rails
/questions/tagged/linux
/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails
/users/483967/yeahwheel
/questions/1378381/Не-могу-поместить-параграф-под-заголовок-на-html-css
/questions/tagged/html
/questions/tagged/css
/questions/tagged/текст
/users/178576/aleksandr-barakin
/questions/1378381/Не-могу-поместить-параграф-под-заголовок-на-html-css?lastactivity
/questions/1378504/yandex-карты-на-react-проекте
/questions/tagged/reactjs
/users/483966/Евгений-Медведев
/questions/1378503/Не-работает-extends-base-html-на-хостинге
/questions/tagged/flask
/questions/tagged/хостинг
/users/431784/neon-light
/questions/1378499/google-analytics-api-трафик-ботов
/questions/tagged/google-analytics
/users/483962/unknown-pjatk
/questions/1378492/Как-получить-определённые-данные-из-строки
/questions/tagged/json
/questions/tagged/строки
/users/441282/pilaton
/questions/1378492/Как-получить-определённые-данные-из-строки?lastactivity
/questions/1378497/Как-через-regeax-в-js-найти-в-тексте-ту-часть-текста-которая-находится-в-нутри-з
/users/483631/Гуг-Оль
/questions/1378494/Как-можно-улучшить-код-Игра-в-крестики-нолики
/questions/tagged/java
/questions/tagged/инспекция-кода
/questions/tagged/динамические-массивы
/users/209304/dmitry
/questions/1378495/Как-мне-в-программу-встроить-установку-иных-программ-и-сертификатов
/questions/tagged/.net
/questions/tagged/winforms
/users/414739/birdbread
/questions/1375209/Сериализация-данных-в-django
/questions/tagged/python-3.x
/questions/tagged/django
/questions/tagged/сериализация
/questions/tagged/django-view
/users/231791/za-ars
/questions/813986/Бот-на-php-для-discord
/questions/tagged/php
/questions/tagged/bot
/questions/tagged/discord-api
/users/-1/Дух-сообщества
/questions/813986/Бот-на-php-для-discord?lastactivity
/questions/1378020/Нужна-ли-ссылка-в-идиоме-обнаружения
/questions/tagged/c++
/questions/tagged/шаблоны-с++
/users/195342/harry
/questions/1378020/Нужна-ли-ссылка-в-идиоме-обнаружения?lastactivity
/questions/1378491/Упаковка-в-exe-проекта-javafx-17-на-gradle-jpackage
/questions/tagged/javafx
/questions/tagged/gradle
/users/461266/addmix
/questions/1378262/Подскажите-как-удалить-поле-order-fully-refunded-в-завершенном-заказе-woocommerc
/questions/tagged/wordpress
/questions/tagged/woocommerce
/users/211900/simon
/questions/1378487/Откуда-undefined-при-создании-массива-в-цикле
/users/180637/splash58
/questions/1378487/Откуда-undefined-при-создании-массива-в-цикле?lastactivity
/questions/1378489/Используя-вызовы-функции-робота-написать-функцию-которая-угадает-число-загада
/questions/tagged/swift
/users/481816/kaban-2000
/questions/1378488/rect-как-заставить-реагировать-компонент-на-изменения-в-другом-компоненте
/users/429629/nothacker
/questions/1378486/Есть-ли-способ-прочитать-effector-store-вне-реакт-компонента-без-использования-g
/questions/tagged/axios
/questions/tagged/state
/users/284916/andrey-zharikov
/questions/1378483/Как-разбить-файл-на-тома
/users/482657/slim-thugs
/questions/1378472/python-работа-со-словарем
/questions/1378472/python-работа-со-словарем?lastactivity
/questions/1378479/Не-удается-вставить-сообщение-пользователя-из-бота-telegram-в-postgres
/questions/tagged/node.js
/questions/tagged/postgresql
/questions/tagged/telegram-bot
/questions/tagged/sequelize.js
/users/464186/anonym
/questions/1378478/c-net6-0-работа-с-изображениями
/users/456985/hlooo
/questions/1378477/Ошибка-при-запуске-тестов
/questions/tagged/юнит-тесты
/users/483956/lerry
/questions/1378292/from-type-in-typescrit-to-string-in-js
/questions/tagged/typescript
/users/447630/user447630
/questions/1378475/thread-java-Метод-run-и-Метод-start
/questions/tagged/многопоточность
/users/204271/sergey-gornostaev
/questions/1378476/Куда-сохраняются-файлы-на-heroku-при-работе-с-телеграмм-ботом
/questions/tagged/heroku
/users/483954/nikita-ermolenko
/questions/1378467/Как-простую-фукнцию-всунут-в-представление-класса
/questions/tagged/классы
/users/206719/Константин
/questions/1378467/Как-простую-фукнцию-всунут-в-представление-класса?lastactivity
/questions/1378471/Как-вызввать-окно-выбора-приложения
/questions/tagged/pyside6
/questions/tagged/pyqt6
/questions/tagged/python-3.10
/users/470095/beecont
/questions/1378465/Как-вывести-title-из-базы-данных-с-помощью-ajax
/questions/tagged/ajax
/users/465363/noreach
/questions/1378465/Как-вывести-title-из-базы-данных-с-помощью-ajax?lastactivity
/questions/1378469/На-какие-библиотеки-по-работе-с-пользователями-стоит-обратить-внимание-asp-net-c
/questions/tagged/asp.net
/questions/tagged/permissions
/questions/tagged/core
/users/483953/ijundev
/questions/1378456/Как-найти-индексы-элементов-одного-списка-внутри-другого
/users/336188/ivan100096
/questions/1378456/Как-найти-индексы-элементов-одного-списка-внутри-другого?lastactivity
/questions/1378466/Использование-хука-acf-save-и-планирование-отключение-wp-cron-событий
/questions/tagged/acf
/users/451868/spoare
/questions/1378450/Как-вызвать-правильно-функцию-с-двумя-escaping-func-examplecompletion1-esca
/questions/tagged/xcode
/users/204219/schmidt9
/questions/1378450/Как-вызвать-правильно-функцию-с-двумя-escaping-func-examplecompletion1-esca?lastactivity
/questions/1378462/ant-design-table-from-nested-json
/questions/tagged/table
/questions/tagged/ant-design
/users/381591/xcplat
/questions/1378459/Как-добавить-поле-сортировки-в-пользовательские-поля
/questions/tagged/битрикс
/users/318496/Юра-Привалов
/questions/1378410/radiobuttons-1-значение-по-умолчанию-2-возможность-поменять-значение
/questions/1378457/На-что-указывает-файловый-дескриптор-и-связь-с-inode
/questions/tagged/c
/users/383123/venot
/questions/1377558/Как-сделать-плавное-перемещение-объекта-в-js-canvas
/questions/tagged/canvas
/users/207200/user207200
/questions/1378455/Примеры-построения-двух-микросервисов-с-использованием-spring-security-и-vaadin
/users/483949/a-universal
/questions/1378390/1С-7-7-Как-сделать-динамическое-добавление-значения-по-ключу-в-документ
/questions/tagged/1с
/users/282213/cardinaltroy
/questions/1378429/Помогите-сделать-анимацию-пушки
/questions/tagged/pygame
/questions/1378442/c-asp-net-mvc-Как-в-форму-веб-приложения-вывести-заполнение-полей-класса
/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc
/users/432677/aliaksandra-manulik
/questions/1378445/Возникает-ошибка-system-argumentoutofrangeexception
/questions/tagged/массивы
/users/260769/crazyelf
/questions/1378445/Возникает-ошибка-system-argumentoutofrangeexception?lastactivity
/questions/1378279/Где-разместить-completion-чтобы-функция-корректно-держала-escaping-виде-массив
/questions/tagged/firebase
/questions/tagged/firestore
/users/470256/Максим-Артемов
/questions/1378279/Где-разместить-completion-чтобы-функция-корректно-держала-escaping-виде-массив?lastactivity
/questions/1378423/Найти-все-ссылки-в-ссылках-c
/questions/tagged/парсер
/users/414626/hekeemje
/questions/1378448/nodejs-получение-данных-с-xlsx-файла
/users/366733/goldhumorist
/questions/1378447/Снятие-pyarmor-с-python-кода
/users/483448/Ярослав-Подъяпольский
/questions/1378444/В-чем-особенность-полиморфизма-для-java-Если-основа-в-java-статическая-типизаци
/users/460777/Артем
/questions/1377834/cmake-3-22-2-не-проходит-билд-openssl-неопределенная-ссылка
/questions/tagged/cmake
/questions/tagged/makefile
/questions/tagged/build
/users/435569/lbsmart
/questions/1378440/ошибка-в-выводе-результата-программы
/questions/tagged/intellij-idea
/users/478312/Вячеслав
/questions/1378438/Ошибка-при-компиляции-проекта-android-org-gradle-api-gradlescriptexception
/questions/tagged/android
/questions/tagged/kotlin
/users/236919/madoka-magica
/questions/1378414/Проблема-с-free-kassa
/questions/tagged/free-kassa
/users/483602/Александр-Конев
/questions/1378326/надо-изменить-значение-в-mysql-таблице-с-помощью-ansible
/questions/tagged/mysql
/questions/tagged/ansible
/questions/tagged/ansible-playbook
/users/473448/alexandr
/questions/1378326/надо-изменить-значение-в-mysql-таблице-с-помощью-ansible?lastactivity
/questions/1378434/Как-определить-минимальное-количество-всех-элементов-в-xsd
/questions/tagged/xml
/questions/tagged/xsd
/users/385867/zhenyria
/questions/1377989/Подтягивание-других-модулей-в-зависимости-при-создании-библиотеки
/questions/tagged/maven
/questions/tagged/modules
/users/308032/svetl9chok
/questions/1378412/typeerror-url-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-name
/users/481068/qckl
/questions/1378412/typeerror-url-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-name?lastactivity
/questions/1378141/sequelize-Как-выполнить-create-для-массива-с-проверкой-на-дубликаты
/users/312617/gelloiss
/questions/1378141/sequelize-Как-выполнить-create-для-массива-с-проверкой-на-дубликаты?lastactivity
/questions/1378425/Что-вернет-xpath-в-php-для-xml
/questions/tagged/xpath
/users/295552/slimrg
/questions/1378405/cant-execute-method-rabbitmq
/questions/tagged/rabbitmq
/users/418901/saba-koghuashvili
/questions/1378405/cant-execute-method-rabbitmq?lastactivity
/questions/1373492/Можно-ли-настроить-aws-sqs-так-чтобы-событие-из-топика-было-считано-всеми-нодами
/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services
/questions/tagged/amazon-sqs
/users/1971/iurii-n
/questions/1373492/Можно-ли-настроить-aws-sqs-так-чтобы-событие-из-топика-было-считано-всеми-нодами?lastactivity
/questions/1378419/Удаление-больших-таблиц-sqlite
/questions/tagged/sqlite
/users/235964/tiarait
/questions/1378316/datetime-utcnow-выдаёт-местное-время
/questions/tagged/дата
/users/483930/pearlfoe
/questions/1378316/datetime-utcnow-выдаёт-местное-время?lastactivity
/questions/1378406/Возвращение-nan-в-vue-js
/questions/tagged/vue.js
/questions/tagged/vue3
/users/382057/kotaine
/questions/1378402/pyqt5-not-loads-image
/questions/tagged/pyqt5
/questions/tagged/изображения
/users/483927/enem
/questions/1378138/Как-использовать-actions-и-state-из-основного-store-в-модулях
/questions/tagged/vuex
/users/300549/vik
/questions/1378138/Как-использовать-actions-и-state-из-основного-store-в-модулях?lastactivity
/questions/1378396/Как-сделать-типизацию-для-ключей-объекта-которые-приняты-как-аргументы
/questions/tagged/типы
/users/190728/alexey-ten
/questions/1378324/Количество-последних-не-уникальных-строк
/questions/tagged/sql
/users/229437/akina
/questions/1378324/Количество-последних-не-уникальных-строк?lastactivity
/questions/1378400/Проблем-с-тестированием-через-jest-puppeteer
/questions/tagged/тестирование
/questions/tagged/puppeteer
/questions/tagged/jest
/users/373019/grokhotun
/questions/1378399/java-jni-defineclass-unsupportedclassversionerror-invalid-class-signature-unk
/questions/tagged/jni
/questions/tagged/classloader
/questions/tagged/bytearray
/users/417091/gru2303
/questions/1375878/Как-загружать-большого-размера-фото-в-oсstore-3-0-3-7
/questions/tagged/opencart
/questions/tagged/ocstore
/users/201560/andrew-hobbit
/questions/1375878/Как-загружать-большого-размера-фото-в-oсstore-3-0-3-7?lastactivity
/questions/1378327/Как-извлечь-значение-в-виде-суммы-из-таблицы-mysql-с-помощью-lua
/questions/tagged/lua
/users/483885/conf-fu
/questions/1378393/Отступы-между-блоками-на-flex
/questions/tagged/вёрстка
/questions/tagged/flexbox
/users/433374/meekwest
/questions/1378338/Как-в-этом-коде-убрать-монетку-после-того-как-до-неё-дотронулся-игрок
/users/235611/alexander-chernin
/questions/1378338/Как-в-этом-коде-убрать-монетку-после-того-как-до-неё-дотронулся-игрок?lastactivity
/questions/1355811/Как-получить-конкретное-значение-цены-при-совершении-события
/questions/tagged/tradingview
/users/472933/andrey-a
/questions/1355811/Как-получить-конкретное-значение-цены-при-совершении-события?lastactivity
/questions/1378389/Объединение-двух-запросов-в-один-единый
/questions/tagged/oracle
/questions/tagged/birt
/users/469193/damnetime
/questions/1376602/Не-подстраивается-обратная-связь-на-opencart-что-бы-сообщения-уходили-от-админи
/questions/1376602/Не-подстраивается-обратная-связь-на-opencart-что-бы-сообщения-уходили-от-админи?lastactivity
/questions/1378384/Выделение-фразы-в-word-через-python
/users/483921/egornovikov
/questions/1369764/1с-запрос-в-sql-базуВнешний-источник-данных
/users/248017/drop
/questions/1378378/Текст-падает-в-обьект-и-другие-обьекты-такие-как-картинки-либо-другой-2д-обьект
/questions/tagged/blender
/users/483916/pain-proper
/questions/1378375/Инструмент-ПО-для-централизованной-установки-ПО-на-армы-под-windows-10
/questions/tagged/windows
/questions/tagged/администрирование
/users/460475/Захар-Елисеев
/questions/1377529/Помогите-спарсить-новостной-сайт
/users/470333/Сергей-Шашко
/questions/1377529/Помогите-спарсить-новостной-сайт?lastactivity
/questions/1378369/Получаю-ошибки-при-использовании-курсора-в-plsql
/questions/tagged/plsql
/questions/tagged/oracle-apex
/questions/tagged/apex
/users/483905/karina
/questions/1378352/Можно-ли-реализовать-аналог-stdendl
/questions/tagged/потоки-данных
/questions/tagged/операторы
/questions/1378352/Можно-ли-реализовать-аналог-stdendl?lastactivity
/questions/1378331/Объединение-2х-collider2d-в-unity2d
/questions/tagged/unity3d
/users/483187/enb
/questions/690433/Валидация-одно-input-на-email-или-телефон-одновременно
/questions/tagged/jquery
/questions/690433/Валидация-одно-input-на-email-или-телефон-одновременно?lastactivity
/questions/1378304/Как-улучшить-вид-вывода-результата-улучшить-читабельность-и-вид-и
/users/186999/grundy
/questions/1378170/laravel-изменить-данные-в-одной-таблице-на-основании-виденных-данных-в-другую-т
/questions/tagged/laravel
/users/256707/Вадим-Александру
/questions/1378170/laravel-изменить-данные-в-одной-таблице-на-основании-виденных-данных-в-другую-т?lastactivity
/questions/956742/Как-пользоваться-rest-api-Битрикс24-в-drupal
/questions/tagged/rest
/questions/tagged/drupal
/questions/tagged/битрикс24
/questions/956742/Как-пользоваться-rest-api-Битрикс24-в-drupal?lastactivity
/questions/1378274/Менеджер-задач-клиент-сервер-java
/users/464893/badziy
/questions/1256327/как-исправить-ошибку-runtimewarning-enable-tracemalloc-to-get-the-object-alloca
/questions/tagged/discord
/questions/tagged/discord-py
/users/217579/0xdb
/questions/1256327/как-исправить-ошибку-runtimewarning-enable-tracemalloc-to-get-the-object-alloca?lastactivity
/questions/tagged/ооп
/questions/tagged/svg
/questions/tagged/css3
/questions/tagged/алгоритм
/questions/tagged/регулярные-выражения
/questions/tagged/html5
/questions/tagged/dataframe
/questions/tagged/aiogram
/questions/tagged/qt
/questions/tagged/сигналы-слоты
/questions/tagged/spring
/questions/tagged/git
/questions/tagged/list
/questions/tagged/telegram
/questions/tagged/qt5
/questions/tagged/pyqt
/questions/tagged/оптимизация
/questions/tagged/requests
/questions/tagged/обработка-данных
/questions/tagged/qtablewidget
/questions/tagged/http
/feeds
/contact
/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour
/users/signup?ssrc=head&returnurl=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour
/users/signup?ssrc=site_switcher&amp;returnurl=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour
/users/login?ssrc=site_switcher&amp;returnurl=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour
/questions/tagged/нейронные-сети
/questions/tagged/web-camera
/help/privileges
/users?tab=moderators
/help/badges/84/informed
/help/badges/2/student
/help/badges/3/editor
/help/badges/24/good-answer
/help/badges/32/civic-duty
/help/badges/28/famous-question
/help/badges
/users/signup?ssrc=about&returnurl=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour#cta
/users/login?ssrc=head
/users/signup?ssrc=head
/users/signup?ssrc=site_switcher
/users/login?ssrc=site_switcher
/users/account-recovery
/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help
/users/signup?ssrc=head&returnurl=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help
/users/signup?ssrc=site_switcher&amp;returnurl=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help
/users/login?ssrc=site_switcher&amp;returnurl=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help
/help/code-golf
/help/on-topic
/help/closed-questions
/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question
/help/quality-standards-error
/help/asking
/help/conduct
/help/searching
/help/browser-support
/help/manifesto
/help/key-values
/help/stackexchange
/help/mod-agreement-policies
/help/staff
/help/locked-posts
/help/whats-reputation
/help/declined-flags
/help/reputation
/help/how-to-answer
/help/self-answer
/help/referencing
/help/deleted-answers
/help/answer-bans
/help/answering
/help/licensing
/help/why-register
/help/deleting-account
/help/creating-accounts
/help/merging-accounts
/help/account
/help/review-close
/help/review-reopen
/help/review-first-answers
/help/review-first-questions
/help/review-late-answers
/help/review-queues
/users/login?ssrc=hero
/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions
/users/signup?ssrc=head&returnurl=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions
/users/signup?ssrc=site_switcher&amp;returnurl=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions
/users/login?ssrc=site_switcher&amp;returnurl=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions
/questions?tab=Newest
/questions?tab=Active
/questions?tab=Bounties
/questions?tab=Unanswered
/questions?tab=Frequent
/questions?tab=Votes
/users/468167/meru382
/questions/1378501/yе-могу-понять-в-чем-заключается-ошибка-python
/users/435474/foora
/users/469835/yrecpodlec
/users/467304/explazy
/users/324704/ivan912
/questions?tab=newest&amp;pagesize=15
/questions?tab=newest&amp;pagesize=30
/questions?tab=newest&amp;pagesize=50
/questions?tab=newest&page=2
/questions?tab=newest&page=3
/questions?tab=newest&page=4
/questions?tab=newest&page=5
/questions?tab=newest&page=27041
/questions/tagged/база-данных
/questions/tagged/wpf
/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags
/users/signup?ssrc=head&returnurl=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags
/users/signup?ssrc=site_switcher&amp;returnurl=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags
/users/login?ssrc=site_switcher&amp;returnurl=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags
/tags/synonyms
/tags?tab=popular
/tags?tab=name
/tags?tab=new
/questions/tagged/javascript?sort=newest&amp;days=1
/questions/tagged/javascript?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/php?sort=newest&amp;days=1
/questions/tagged/php?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/python?sort=newest&amp;days=1
/questions/tagged/python?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/java?sort=newest&amp;days=1
/questions/tagged/java?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/c#?sort=newest&amp;days=1
/questions/tagged/c#?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/html?sort=newest&amp;days=1
/questions/tagged/html?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/android?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/android?sort=newest&amp;days=30
/questions/tagged/c++?sort=newest&amp;days=1
/questions/tagged/c++?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/css?sort=newest&amp;days=1
/questions/tagged/css?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/jquery?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/jquery?sort=newest&amp;days=30
/questions/tagged/python-3.x?sort=newest&amp;days=1
/questions/tagged/python-3.x?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/mysql?sort=newest&amp;days=1
/questions/tagged/mysql?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/sql?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/sql?sort=newest&amp;days=30
/questions/tagged/linux?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/linux?sort=newest&amp;days=30
/questions/tagged/c?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/c?sort=newest&amp;days=30
/questions/tagged/массивы?sort=newest&amp;days=1
/questions/tagged/массивы?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/wordpress?sort=newest&amp;days=1
/questions/tagged/wordpress?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/django?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/django?sort=newest&amp;days=30
/questions/tagged/node.js?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/node.js?sort=newest&amp;days=30
/questions/tagged/ajax?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/ajax?sort=newest&amp;days=30
/questions/tagged/json?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/json?sort=newest&amp;days=30
/questions/tagged/база-данных?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/база-данных?sort=newest&amp;days=30
/questions/tagged/wpf?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/wpf?sort=newest&amp;days=30
/questions/tagged/алгоритм?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/алгоритм?sort=newest&amp;days=30
/questions/tagged/reactjs?sort=newest&amp;days=1
/questions/tagged/reactjs?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/windows?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/windows?sort=newest&amp;days=30
/questions/tagged/.net?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/.net?sort=newest&amp;days=30
/questions/tagged/регулярные-выражения?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/регулярные-выражения?sort=newest&amp;days=30
/questions/tagged/unity3d?sort=newest&amp;days=1
/questions/tagged/unity3d?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/qt?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/qt?sort=newest&amp;days=30
/questions/tagged/css3?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/css3?sort=newest&amp;days=30
/questions/tagged/html5?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/html5?sort=newest&amp;days=30
/questions/tagged/laravel?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/laravel?sort=newest&amp;days=30
/questions/tagged/winforms?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/winforms?sort=newest&amp;days=30
/questions/tagged/веб-программирование
/questions/tagged/веб-программирование?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/веб-программирование?sort=newest&amp;days=30
/questions/tagged/ubuntu
/questions/tagged/ubuntu?sort=newest&amp;days=7
/questions/tagged/ubuntu?sort=newest&amp;days=30
/tags?page=2&tab=popular
/tags?page=3&tab=popular
/tags?page=4&tab=popular
/tags?page=5&tab=popular
/tags?page=161&tab=popular
```

Comment: спасибо большое, буду сидеть разбираться теперь изучать всё ) 
вот только что проверил парочку сайтов, все отработали отлично, только вот сайт - dou.ua как то странно себя ведёт , пару раз подряд всё окей отлично отрабатывает, а затем раз за разом Exception, через минуту-две пробую - всё норм , затем иногда снова Exception
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.SelectSingleNode(...) returned null.

в строке Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head/title").InnerText.Trim());

Comment: @hekeemje NullReferenceException исправил. Если ответ был полезен, вы знаете, что делать. :)

Comment: @hekeemje Чтобы некоторые сайты вас не блочили, можно задержку между запросами добавлять, например запрос не чаще, чем 5 раз в секунду. И другие алгоритмы обхода ошибок. Исключения я здесь особо не обрабатывал, добавьте обработчиков. Про семафор я не зря сказал, может наблодиться очень-очень много тасок, если не притормаживать рост. Контроллируйте глубину переходов. Очень часто можно попасть на циклические переходы, хотя ссылки с виду будут разные. Можно добавить проверку названий страниц, и т.д.

Comment: понял хорошо, поработаю над этим как разберусь в этом новом )

Comment: извините может за тупой вопрос : рекурсия вызывается вот здесь "tasks.Add(ParsePage(uri, depth - 1));" ?

Comment: Рекурсия - это когда метод вызывает сам себя. Либо 2 метода циклически вызывают друг друга, и т.д.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133856/discussion-between-hekeemje-and-aepot).