# узнать время отклика для URL C#

Tags: c#, ping

Как узнать ping ( время отклика ) для любого URL , class Ping не подходит так как время отклика покажет для ****.com к примеру, а вот для ****.com/about уже не будет показывать

Comment: Пинг до сервера одинаковый, что для `/`, что для `/about`, так как это один и тот же сервер. А вот время обработки запроса может быть разным, плюс время передачи данных. Что именно вам требуется?

Comment: @aepot сколько время обработки запроса ?

Comment: Запускаете секундомер перед отправкой запроса, останавливаете при полном получении ответа. Не вижу проблемы.

Comment: @aepot 
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
               Так же пробовал не хочет для ссылок по типу /about

Comment: `HttpWebRequest` засуньте это ископаемое времен динозавров туда, где взяли. У вас есть `HttpClient` и мой прошлый ответ с ним.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class GetAsyncUrl
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _client;

        public GetAsyncUrl()
        {
        _client = new HttpClient();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36");
        }

        public async Task showAsyncTime(string url)
        {
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Restart();
            await _client.GetStringAsync(url);
            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Зачем `HttpRequestMessage`? В данном случае он бесполезен, достаточно простого `.GetAsync(...);`. Также я надеюсь, `HttpClient` вы не каждый раз создаете? Помните, он должен быть один, на все приложение!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ подправил код

Comment: Вот это хороший код, но я бы для надежности вычитывал контент, типа `.GetStringAsync(url)` вместо `GetAsync`.

Comment: Если этот метод надо вызывать несколько раз, то лучше `sw.Restart();` вместо `sw.Start();`

Comment: @aepot исправил

Comment: @aepot я видел вы отправляли правильное использование метода ? не могли бы показать ? а то вот пытаюсь его использовать с коллекцией ссылок url в foreach и что то проблемы возникают, хотя при одиночном отлично работает

Comment: @aepot ещё проблема оказалась в том что забыл указать "_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36");" весь день ломал голову что не так, оказалось вот в чём была))

Comment: @hekeemje кстати эту строчку вы можете в любой момент вытащить из своего браузера, откройте инструменты разработчика, вкладака Сеть, обновите страницу и посмотрите в любой запрос, там будет эта строчка в заголовках запроса.

Comment: @aepot вижу да, какой материал стоить почитать чтобы понять лучше всё это ?

Comment: Основы TCP/IP и HTTP.

Comment: @aepot у меня есть куча URL и мне надо их загнать в этот метод , для~100 URL довольно таки не быстро получу результат , хотел использовать lock чтобы обработать все URL быстро , но понял что lock нельзя использовать с await, есть ли какое то решение этого чтобы быстро обработать все URL этим методом ?

Comment: Я уже раз 5 вам [эту ссылку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567) кидал.