# Как распараллелить выполнение задач?

Tags: c#

Мне необходимо распарсить сайт с гос.закупками за каждый месяц года. Как сделать выполнение данных задач параллельными?

```
    public async Task<IList<Auction>> GetResultAuction(string dateFrom, string dateTo, string fileName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Start: {fileName}");

        var auctions = new List<Auction>();

        var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();

        var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);

        var pages = await GetPagesAsync(dateFrom, dateTo);

        foreach (var page in pages.ToArray())
        {
            string number = page.Url.Split("=").Last();

            string url =
                $"https://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/notice/ea20/view/supplier-results.html?regNumber={number}";

            var document = await context.OpenAsync(url);

            var cells = document.QuerySelectorAll("#supplier-def-result-participant-table-28901226 .blockInfo__table.tableBlock .tableBlock__body .tableBlock__row td:nth-child(3)")
                .Select(x => x.TextContent.Trim()).ToArray();

            if (cells is { Length: > 0 } && cells[1] == cells[2])
            {
                var auction = new Auction
                {
                    Number = number,
                    Object = document.QuerySelector(".cardMainInfo__content")?.TextContent,
                    Url = $"https://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/notice/ea20/view/common-info.html?regNumber={number}"
                };

                auctions.Add(auction);
            }
        }

        return auctions;
    }

    private async Task<IList<Page>> GetPagesAsync(string dateFrom, string dateTo)
    {
        var pages = new List<Page>();

        var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();

        var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            string url =
                $"https://zakupki.gov.ru/epz/order/extendedsearch/results.html?morphology=on&search-filter=+%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F&pageNumber={i}&sortDirection=false&recordsPerPage=_200&showLotsInfoHidden=false&sortBy=PUBLISH_DATE&fz44=on&pc=on&placingWayList=EA44%2CEAP44%2CEA20%2CEAP20%2CEAB44%2CEAO44%2CEAO20%2CEAB20%2CEEA44%2CEEA20&selectedLaws=FZ44&priceFromGeneral=50000&priceToGeneral=10000000&currencyIdGeneral=1&publishDateFrom={dateFrom}&publishDateTo={dateTo}";

            var document = await context.OpenAsync(url);

            var cells = document.QuerySelectorAll(".registry-entry__header-mid__number a")
                .Select(x => x.GetAttribute("href"));

            foreach (var cell in cells)
            {
                var page = new Page
                {
                    Url = cell
                };

                pages.Add(page);
            }
        }

        return pages;
    }
```

Я подумал, что будет правильно создать коллекцию задач и вызвать метод await Task.WhenAll()

Не возникнут ли у меня в этом коде проблемы с конкуренцией?

```
var tasks = new List<Task<IList<Auction>>>();

ParserService parserService = new ParserService();

tasks.Add(parserService.GetResultAuction("01.01.2021", "31.01.2021", "January"));

tasks.Add(parserService.GetResultAuction("01.02.2021", "27.02.2021", "February"));

var result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567

Comment: `Не возникнут ли у меня в этом коде проблемы с конкуренцией?` - это зависит от используемых общих между потоками ресурсов. Сходу таких не вижу. Если сильно распараллелитесь, можете получить бан по IP от веб-сервера, который посчитает вас ботом (и правильно сделает). Так что знайте меру.