# Балансировщик с лимитом на длину очереди

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Есть веб-API сервис на `ASP.NET Core`. Он, в свою очередь, в своей работе пользуется другим веб-сервисом, точнее несколькими одинаковыми сервисами.
Запросы на эти подчиненные сервисы занимают от 100 ms до 10 секунд времени.

Нужно равномерно распределить нагрузку на подчиненные сервисы, с ограничением количества одновременных запросов на сервис.

Решение требуется в рамках головного сервиса.

Пример. Подчиненных сервисов всего несколько (2-5), длина очереди - не более 30 одновременных запросов на сервис.

Какие есть варианты, может быть есть готовые решения?
Буду рад любым идеям или подсказкам.

Comment: Producer/Consumer вас спасет. Например на базе `System.Threading.Channels`. И [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567) загляните.

Comment: @aepot спасибо, то, что нужно, вы можете оформить это как ответ :)

Comment: Это был скорее не ответ, а подсказка, куда копать. Вы можете оформить ответ сами, добавив больше деталей.

Comment: В .NET7 появился [Rate Limiting](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-rate-limiting-for-dotnet/)