# HttpClient, использование памяти

Tags: c#

Приложение запускает несколько потоков с бесконечными циклами, которые выполняют sql и web запросы, при работе используемая память бесконечно увеличивается. Не понимаю из-за чего, предполагаю, что проблема именно в web запросах. Вот снимок кучи и метод который используется в циклах, для выполнения запроса через прокси если тот имеется.
[image: к]

```
        public static async Task<string> GETOrProxy(string url, string[] proxy)
        {
            string result = null;
            try
            {
                if (proxy[0] != "" && proxy[0] != null)
                {

                    WebProxy Proxy = new WebProxy
                    {
                        Address = new Uri($"http://{proxy[0]}:{proxy[1]}"),
                        BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
                        UseDefaultCredentials = false,

                        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                        userName: proxy[2],
                        password: proxy[3])
                    };
                    var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler{Proxy = Proxy};
                    using var client = new HttpClient(handler: httpClientHandler, disposeHandler: true);
                    var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                    result = Convert.ToString(response);
                    httpClientHandler.Dispose();
                }
                else
                {

                    using var client = new HttpClient();
                    var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                    result = Convert.ToString(response);
                }
            }
            catch 
            {

                result = null;
            }
            
  
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Версию дотнета скажите. И `несколько потоков с бесконечными циклами` не вижу ни одного потока и ни одного цикла у вас в коде. Нужен воспроизводимый пример. Могу сказать только 2 вещи: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567) и то что не надо пересоздавать клиент для одной и той же прокси. А если без прокси, то и вовсе одного клиента хватит. Документацию по HttpClient хоть раз читали? _HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use._

Comment: Посмотрел скрин подробнее, судя по всему, это устаревший .NET Framework 4.x, используйте .NET 6, если хотите производительности и контролируйте количество одновременно работающих клиентов, тогда не будет проблем с памятью.

Comment: @aepot .NET 6, одновременно работают 10 потоков, это максимум 10 клиентов(одновременно). Разве это может привести к бесконечному потреблению? Доходило до 28гб, разве после закрытия клиента вся использованная им память не освобождается?

Comment: Ограничение работает не на количество создаваемых оъектов, а на количество установленных соединений.

Comment: Я создал тестовый проект, и через тот же метод запустил цикл с 1 потока - всё нормально память не увеличивается, запускаю 2 идентичный поток - память начинает медленно расти. это о чём-то говорит?

Comment: Это говорит о том, что вам нужен пул клиентов, фабрика, которая будет кешировать клиенты с одинаоковыми проксями, а не создавать их каждый раз заново.

Comment: А нет, несколько потоков занимают в разы больше памяти, но не бесконечно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я избавился от создания нового HttpClient для каждого запроса и проблема ушла. Насчёт прокси - я работаю с разными аккаунтами(для каждого свой прокси) и теперь для каждого аккаунта создаётся свой httpclient, если у аккаунта нет прокси - client создаётся без handler. И этот клиент уже отправляется в метод запроса.