# Фильтрация больших данных

Tags: c#, сортировка, оптимизация, linq, filter

у меня есть список улиц с указанием города (более 50к значений). Необходимо написать более быстрый метод фильтрации этого списка для последующей выдачи результатов пользователю.
Сейчас у меня такой вариант:

```
var list = AddressList.Where(x=> x.Contains("Гагарина");
```

Работает не плохо, но может кто знает как можно делать это быстрее или проще ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Проще вроде некуда. А вот быстрее - я бы попробовал разделить заранее адреса на части, чтобы проверять только улицу, например. Это явно будет быстрее, чем в целом адресе искать. Ну и там были нюансы ещё какие запросы выполняются на сервере, а какие на клиенте, может в эту сторону покопать. Так то для SQL сервера это не сложный совсем запрос же.

Comment: Есть отличное решение вашей задачи - разделение коллекции на несколько частей и параллельная её обработка. Посмотрите вот этот вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/378277. В заголовке представлен пример использования семафоров. Вам нужно лишь написать метод-таску, которая фильтрует данные по вашему условию. Так же, можно рассмотреть решение из вопроса по следующей ссылке https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/32162. Насколько оно рабочее - сказать не могу. Так же, если вы работаете с БД при помощи EntityFramework, помните, что `IQueryable` обладает асинхронными методами

Comment: проще - никак. Быстрее возможно, если отказаться от списка и воспользоваться какой-нибудь другой структурой данных, например деревом