# Unable to read data from the transport connection System.IO.IOException

Tags: c#, httpclient, parallel

Есть задача - асинхронно распарсить данные, get запросов очень много, поэтому решил распараллелить вот таким образом.

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    Parallel.ForEach(collection, (itemFrom) =>
    {
        foreach (var itemTo in collection)
        {
            List<ResponseModel> result = default;
            try
            {
                result = (List<ResponseModel>)ParseByCurrencyAsync(itemFrom.Key, itemTo.Key).Result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex){ }
        }
    });
});
```

В результате получаю ошибку из заголовка темы, ну и вот это дело
[image: code]

Почитал информацию по данной ошибке, судя по всему истекает время ожидания ответа.
Видимо очень много запросов и сервер их блокирует.
Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какое то решение для данной задачи?

Comment: Исходный код принято размещать в виде текста.

Comment: Извиняюсь, поправил

Comment: А разве не нужно делать `await ParseByCurrencyAsync`?

Comment: а я там свойство Result вызываю, оно же вроде эквивалентно ожиданию...или нет?

Comment: Ну вы попробуйте. По-моему результат можно смотреть только когда он уже готов.

Comment: В документации написано "Доступ к методу доступа к свойству блокирует вызывающий поток до завершения асинхронной операции; Он эквивалентен вызову Wait метода." Я так понял, что Result ждёт. Попробую конечно await, но обычно раньше Result всегда хватало...

Comment: А, ну да, наверное. Просто нерационально ждёт, не отпуская поток, а так, наверное, можно. Ну тогда саму функцию `ParseByCurrencyAsync` надо разбирать. Если вас блокирует сервер - ну, пробуйте менять хедеры, а то и `ip` надо менять, прокси ротировать. Простые методы вряд ли есть.

Comment: похоже, что да... единственное... я думал может ещё как то попробовать время ожидания ответа увеличить

Comment: Нужно подробнее ошибку как-то посмотреть, сейчас это краткое какое-то описание.

Comment: да, похоже я перебрал с запросами) сервак включил ддос защиту

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исключение возвращает метод `ParseByCurrencyAsync`, и показанный код здесь не при чем. Но это плохой код, технически и семантически. Вот хороший эквивалент:

```
var tasks = new List<Task<List<ResponseModel>>>();
foreach (var itemTo in collection)
{
    tasks.Add(ParseByCurrencyAsync(itemFrom.Key, itemTo.Key));
}
List<ResponseModel>[] result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Но я на вашем месте бы задумался над ограничением количества одновременно работающих запросов

- [Массовые асинхронные вызовы с ограничением на количество параллельных без семафора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567)

---

Никогда не используйте `.Result`, его можно использовать только для завершенных задач, например пусть будет некий `task` типа `Task<int>`:

```
// ВОТ ТАК НЕЛЬЗЯ
int number = task.Result;
```

Этот код повесит текущий поток до окончания работы метода, то есть ровно так, как если бы вы выполняли просто синхронный код.

Другой пример

```
// вот так можно
await task;
int number = task.Result;
```

А проще

```
int number = await task;
```

Как видите, практической пользы от `.Result` никакой, но она иногда есть, вот рабочий пример, где я не знаю, синхронно завершился вызванный метод или асинхронно (да, такое тоже бывает):

```
if (!task.IsCompleted)
{
    await task;
}
int number = task.Result;
```

Что-то вроде оптимизации, запускаю ожидание только если нужно. Но случай действительно редкий и большинство разработчиков, чтобы не путатья сделают проще `int number = await task;`, и я вам тоже советую использовать только `await`, и никак иначе.

Comment: Большое спасибо, это очень полезная информация