# На сколько потоков разбивать пагинацию C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, parallel

Коллеги добрый день! Новичок в параллельном программирование, возник такой вопрос. У меня есть система из которой можно запрашивать сущность в ней реализована пагинация. Мне нужно эффективно выгружать эти сущности.
Какое решение я вижу, в коде получать количество ядер и на столько парралельных потоков разбивать пагинацию. вопрос насколько такое решение правильное, и как можно сделать лучше ?

Comment: обычно, когда мне нужно парсить страницы сайта, я использую [`Parallel.For`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=net-6.0), внутри которого происходит парсинг `i`-той страницы, таким образом все страницы парсяться паралельно и удобно. Не могу сравнить эффективность с вашим подходом, но то, что `Parallel.For` является встроеным решением, даёт основания доверять, что оно достаточно эффективно работает

Comment: Ну вот надо выгрузить 2000 записей, и как ? Используя пагинацию с размером страницы 10, сделать 200 потоков ? Думаете это лучше чем 4 параллельных (если 4 ядра) в каждом по 50

Comment: `Environment.ProcessorCount * 2` https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567

Comment: @iiKuzmychov `он выполняет каждую итерацию как Task` не так, он просто использует пул потоков, вам стоит покопаться в теме поглубже. `Task` это ожидалка, он сам по себе к многопоточке отношения никакого не имеет.

Comment: Мне кажется, вы термин "пагинация" используете не в том смысле, как обычно принято. Пользователь запрашивает, например, 5-ю страницу, на странице 10 записей - он получает только их - это пагинация. При чём здесь многопоточка/распараллеливание совершенно неясно. Может, вам нужно _обработать_ максимально быстро все 2000 записей? Это _не_ пагинация.