# Обработка массива данных в несколько потоков

Tags: c#, .net

Имеется большой массив данных, который обрабатывается несколькими потоками одновременно (сами элементы массива не изменяются, а лишь читаются). Необходимо реализовать функционал, который позволяет равномерно распределить работу: у каждого потока в любой момент времени есть 1 обрабатываемый элемент, завершив работу с этим элементом, вызывается метод `GetItem()`, который запрашивает следующий элемент. Как идея: создать внутренний словарь где ключом будет идентификатор потока, а значением - позиция обрабатываемого элемента. При вызове метода `GetItem()` осуществляется потокобезопасный поиск номера элемента, который может быть следующим (номер на единицу больше наибольшего из номеров, обрабатываемых в настоящий момент, либо наименьший номер находящий между соседними отсортированными по возрастанию номерами с разницей больше 1). Так же следует избежать копирования самого массива - необходимо лишь вытаскивать в нужный момент элемент с определённым номером.

Просто разделить весь массив на несколько равных по размеру сегментов и скормить соответствующему количеству потоков не подходит, так как время обработки каждого элемента может сильно отличаться, и в то время как один поток завершит обработку, другие будут простаивать.

**UPD:** Работа всех потоков может быть прервана и тогда важно сохранить номера обрабатываемых элементов, чтобы в следующий раз можно было с них же начать.

Comment: [Имплементация Producer/Consumer pattern](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/428327/179763)

Comment: @tym32167 Возможно ли создать из массива объект `BlockingCollecting` избегая копирования элементов? Мне кажется нет. Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Не понял про копирование. Если вам надо сохранять обработанные индексы - сделайте второй массив и туда сохраняйте.

Comment: Мне кажется можно использовать `ConcurrentQueue`. При остановке работы можно запомнить оставшееся количество элементов (вычитая из  общего количества элементов получим значение числа элементов, которые нужно отсечь с начала массива при возобновлении работы). _"Не понял про копирование."_ - исходный массив очень большой по размеру, при создании того же экземпляра `ConcurrentQueue` в конструктор передаётся `IEnumerable` - произойдёт ли копирования элементов в какую-нибудь внутреннюю коллекцию? То есть не хотелось бы иметь в памяти 2 одинаковых больших набора данных.

Comment: [По всей видимости](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentQueue.cs,cc1417d322ff0a9e,references) внутри создаётся некоторый `Segment`, который, я полагаю, похож на `ArraySegment` и не содержит самих элементов, а лишь указывает на сегмент исходной коллекции.

Comment: Про количество - ну вот вы отправите обрабатываться элементы 1-10 и нажмёте стоп, к этому времени обработаться успеют элементы 6 и 10 например. Как вы это опишете «оставшимися количеством элементов»?

Comment: Про то, что исходный массив «очень большой» я не понял. Расскажите в числах. Сколько элементов, сколько памяти занимает каждый и так далее. «Очень большой» -это по сути не описывает ничего

Comment: Про копирование - если ваши элементы в массиве ссылочного типа, то создание новой коллекции просто копирует ссылки на них, а не все данные. Например, если у вас массив строк, создание очереди с ними будет копировать ссылки на те же строки.

Comment: [Массовые асинхронные вызовы с ограничением на количество параллельных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567)

Comment: _"Про количество - ну вот вы отправите обрабатываться элементы 1-10 и нажмёте стоп, к этому времени обработаться успеют элементы 6 и 10 например. Как вы это опишете «оставшимися количеством элементов»?"_ - Каждый поток берёт из очереди по 1 элементу. Невозможно же взять 6 и 10 элементы, не взяв при этом все с 1 по 10.

Comment: _"Сколько элементов, сколько памяти занимает каждый"_ - Около полумиллиона элементов, суммарный размер 120 МБайт. Размер каждого элемента разный.

Comment: _"если ваши элементы в массиве ссылочного типа, то создание новой коллекции просто копирует ссылки на них, а не все данные." - Вообще да, но скопировать ссылки тоже может быть затратно если их очень много. `ArraySegment` к примеру не хранит ни ссылок ни самих элементов.

Comment: @aepot Не нашёл ответа на свой вопрос.