# Использование миллионов Task-ов приводит к ошибке System.OutOfMemoryException (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, .net-6

У меня есть 6 миллионов небольших (средний размер около 15 байт) файлов, которые мне нужно прочитать и далее обработать с помощью процессора. Я ранее реализовал это с помощью `Task.Factory` и всё работало без проблем на asp .net core 2.1. Занимало по времени около 20 часов.

Теперь я перенес приложение на asp.net 6 и на тестовом сервере мое веб-приложение перестает отвечать на любые запросы после запуска этих файловых операций и аварийно завершается. В логах я вижу ошибку `System.OutOfMemoryException`.

Я полагаю, что мой способ реализации далек от идеала. Я хотел бы узнать какие-нибудь иные способы многопоточной реализации этой работы или ваши замечания по текущему коду.

Метод контроллера `ImportSignatures`:

```
[HttpPost("ImportSignatures")]
public async Task<JsonResult> ImportSignatures()
{
    try
    {
        ImportSigningCertsResult res = await SignatureImportService.ImportSigningCerts();
        return Json(res);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogsHelper.WriteLog("api/Settings/ImportSignatures", e);
        return Json(new ImportSigningCertsResult(e.Message, SignatureImportService.WasCancelled));
    }
}
```

Метод `ImportSigningCerts`:

```
public static async Task<ImportSigningCertsResult> ImportSigningCerts()
{
    LogsHelper.WriteEventLog("Запуск SignatureImportService");
    WasCancelled = false;
    IsWorking = true;
    ResultStr = "";
    totalSignatures = 0;
    processedSignatures = 0;

    var cancelMsg = "Импорт сертификатов был прерван. \n";
    var endMsg = "Импорт сертификатов успешно завершён. \n";
    var toDelete = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        var configuration = SignatureImportConfiguration.FromCfg();

        using (s_tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            IEnumerable<string> signatures = Directory.EnumerateFiles(configuration.Path, "*.sig");
            totalSignatures = signatures.Count();

            Store mainStore = StoreMan.GetStore("Main");
            var importStats = new ImportStats();
            List<Task> tasks = new();

            int saveIndex = 1;
            const int proccessedForSave = 100000; // Через какое кол-во обработанных подписей произвести промежуточное сохранение хранилища и удаление подписей
            CancellationToken token = s_tokenSource.Token;

            ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out int minWorkerThreads, out _);
            using SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new(minWorkerThreads);

            foreach (string path in signatures)
            {
                semaphore.Wait();

                if (WasCancelled)
                    break;

                tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                        if (UploadSigningCerts(mainStore, path, importStats))
                        {
                            if (configuration.NeedCleaning)
                            {
                                lock (s_toDeleteListLockObj)
                                    toDelete.Add(path);
                            }
                        }

                        Interlocked.Increment(ref processedSignatures);
                        lock (s_intermediateSaveLockObj)
                        {
                            if (processedSignatures > proccessedForSave * saveIndex)
                            {
                                LogsHelper.WriteEventLog("Промежуточное сохранение хранилища сертификатов...");

                                mainStore.WriteIfChanged();
                                StartRemovingSignatures(toDelete);
                                saveIndex++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        if (e is not OperationCanceledException)
                            LogsHelper.WriteLog("SignatureImportService/ImportSigningCerts:Task.Factory.StartNew", e);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        semaphore.Release();
                    }
                }, token));
            }

            try
            {
                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) { }

            mainStore.WriteIfChanged();
            StartRemovingSignatures(toDelete);
            ResultStr = (WasCancelled ? cancelMsg : endMsg) + $"Certificates found: {importStats.all}. Was imported: {importStats.imported}." + (importStats.parsingFailed > 0 ? $" Unrecognized files: {importStats.parsingFailed}" : "");
        }

        LogsHelper.WriteEventLog(ResultStr);
        return s_tokenSource == null ? new ImportSigningCertsResult(ResultStr) : new ImportSigningCertsResult(ResultStr, WasCancelled);
    }
    finally
    {
        IsWorking = false;
    }
}
```

Метод `UploadSigningCerts`:

```
private static bool UploadSigningCerts(Store store, string path, ImportStats importStats)
{
    bool toBeDeleted = true;
    CryptoClient client = CryptoServiceContext.DefaultInstance.CryptoClient;

    try
    {
        List<CertInfo> certs = client.GetSignCmsInfo(File.ReadAllBytes(path)).Certs.ToList();

        Interlocked.Add(ref importStats.all, certs.Count);

        for (int i = 0; i < certs.Count; i++)
        {
            lock (s_importLockObj)
            {
                // Код по валидации каждого сертификата из файла, принятие решения об импорте, импорт в хранилище...
            }
        }
        return toBeDeleted;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogsHelper.WriteLog("SignatureImportService/UploadSigningCerts", e);
        LogsHelper.WriteEventLog($"Ошибка импорта сертификата из подписи: {Path.GetFileName(path)};");
        Interlocked.Increment(ref importStats.errors);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Метод `StartRemovingSignatures`:

```
private static void StartRemovingSignatures(List<string> toDelete)
{
    if (toDelete.Count > 0)
    {
        List<string> tempToDelete;
        lock (s_toDeleteListLockObj)
        {
            tempToDelete = new List<string>(toDelete);
            toDelete.Clear();
        }

        LogsHelper.WriteEventLog("Удаление успешно обработанных файлов подписей...");

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            tempToDelete.ForEach(path =>
            {
                try
                {
                    File.Delete(path);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    LogsHelper.WriteLog("ImportResult/DeleteSignatures", e);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Текст ошибки:

```
20.08.2023 11:58:01 api/Settings/ImportSignatures
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.EnsureContingentPropertiesInitializedUnsafe()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.AssignCancellationToken(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Task antecedent, TaskContinuation continuation)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.TaskConstructorCore(Delegate action, Object state, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions, InternalTaskOptions internalOptions, TaskScheduler scheduler)
   at Store.Services.SignatureImportService.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<ImportSigningCerts>b__0(String path)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
   at Store.Services.SignatureImportService.ImportSigningCerts()
   at Store.Controllers.SettingsController.ImportSignatures()
```

**Updated: код был отредактирован**

Comment: 6 млн файлов в одной папке - это ахтунг для большинства файловых систем. | Открытие/закрытие файла - это медленная операция. 6 млн открытий/закрытий - это очень долго. Глобальное решение проблемы: хранить эти подписи в небольшом количестве файлов. Или в какой-нибудь БД, например, в sqlite.

Comment: На веб-серверах не рекомендуется использовать многопоточность/параллельность. Все потоки заняты обработкой этих файлов - нет свободных потоков для обработки запросов. Вот сервер и не отвечает. | Нужна асинхронность! Хотелось бы увидеть метод `UploadSigningCerts`. Можно не весь код, а только тот, что использует файл.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, к сожалению, вопрос хранения подписей невозможно изменить... Имеем 6 млн файлов... Код метода `UploadSigningCerts` добавил.

Comment: Почему невозможно? Можно считать подпись и как binary закинуть в базу, например. К комментариям выше присоединяюсь, 6млн файлов это что-то слишком уже...

Comment: _Мой код:_ - а метод, в котором он находится не показали, что Это за метод, синхронный он, асинхронный, контроллер или что? вы просто уложили сервер таким кодом, вот пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567, надо ограничивать использование ресурсов.

Comment: @Deadooshka нельзя использовать GC.Collect, и тем более другми это советовать, и тем более на серверах. GC при недостатке памяти и так всё агрессивно соберет. Ваш совет не только бесполезен на 100% но и вреден, может добавить тормозов к и без того нерабочему коду, а проблему не решит.

Comment: @aepot данный код - синхронный метод контроллера.

Comment: Добавьте сигнатуру метода в вопрос, то есть метод целиком, я могу сделать его асинхронным, чтобы не вешать сервер, но я не вижу самого метода, чтобы решить эту проблему.

Comment: Вот ещё что скажу. 6 млн файлов по 15 байт - это меньше ста мегабайт. Но! Каждый файл будет занимать минимум один кластер в файловой системе. По умолчанию кластер равен 4 кб. Итого 6 млн файлов займут 24 Гб! Меняйте способ хранения. Меняйте!

Comment: @aepot, сделал вызов метода в контроллере и последующий вызов `ImportSigningCerts` асинхронными, немного рефакторинга. Ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста. С данным кодом всё стало работать раза в 2 быстрее... Под конец (после 4.5 млн обработанных файлов) опять словил ошибку по памяти - я думаю, это из-за коллекции Task-ов, которые у меня копятся для отслеживания в конце их финиша. Быть может, в моей ситуации стоит посмотреть в какую-то другую сторону, не использовать Task-и?

Comment: Да, стало лучше, но здесь много ещё чего можно улучшить. Я напишу ответ как освобожусь.

Comment: @aepot, читал ещё посты другие на stackoverflow, наткнулся на схожую проблему с памятью при работе с тасками. Там предложили разделить общее кол-во на "порции". У меня вот в коде есть как раз промежуточное сохранение через каждые 100тыс файлов - думаю, можно сделать ожидание завершения задач на этом этапе и затем приступать к обработке очередной "порции". Таким образом массив будет содержать максимально 100тыс задач вместо 6.5 млн. Что думаете о таком подходе?

Comment: А зачем вообще параллелизм. Разве диск по своей природе не синхронный? Может какие ssd-диски и позволяют аппаратно асинхронность, но в обычных дисках головка записи не может распараллелиться.

Comment: @Deadooshka по мат части вам ничего не могу ответить, но опытным путём проверено, что в моём случае разделение на потоки даёт буст в 2 с лишним раза по скорости обработки всех файлов. Согласитесь - есть разница между 8ч и 20ч работы... Да и все эти операции включают в себя не только работу с файлами, но и процессорную часть...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте попробуем этот код стабилизировать

- нужно избавиться от лишних делегатов
- нет смысла гонять файловую систему из кучи потоков, она синхронная, она не может в рамках одного носителя выполнять кучу операций одновременно
- нет смысла трогать настройки пула потоков, он нормально настроен, просто нужно относиться к нему бережно
- нельзя блокировать поток контроллера, так вы вешаете весь сервер, для этого есть асинхронные операции
- много локов - плохо для понимания кода и производительности, используйте потокобезопасные коллекции
- процедура чтения int переменной атомарна сама по себе, поэтому lock не нужен для чтения, избавиться от лишних локов
- полностью избавиться от статики
- ограничить количество одновременно работающих задач до количества ядер сервера, умноженное на два (так исторически сложилось, что это оптимально, с этого надо начинать)
- каждый созданный вами Task должен быть ожидаемым, так вы получаете контроль над процессом и удобнее ловить исключения
- удаление файлов можно вообще через Producer/Consumer сделать, чтобы удалялись сразу как появляются в череди на удаление, при этом не тормозили основной код.

Вот и получается как-то так

```
[HttpPost("ImportSignatures")]
public async Task<JsonResult> ImportSignatures()
{
    SignatureImportService importService = new SignatureImportService();
    try
    {
        ImportSigningCertsResult res = await importService.ImportSigningCerts();
        return Json(res);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogsHelper.WriteLog("api/Settings/ImportSignatures", e);
        return Json(new ImportSigningCertsResult(e.Message, importService.WasCancelled));
    }
}
```

```
public async Task<ImportSigningCertsResult> ImportSigningCerts()
{
    LogsHelper.WriteEventLog("Запуск SignatureImportService");

    const string cancelMsg = "Импорт сертификатов был прерван. \n";
    const string endMsg = "Импорт сертификатов успешно завершён. \n";
    try
    {
        using (_cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            var configuration = SignatureImportConfiguration.FromCfg();
            string[] signatures = Directory.GetFiles(configuration.Path, "*.sig");
            totalSignatures = signatures.Length;
            processedSignatures = 0;

            Store mainStore = StoreMan.GetStore("Main");
            var importStats = new ImportStats();
            List<Task> tasks = new();

            int saveIndex = 1;
            const int proccessedForSave = 100000; // Через какое кол-во обработанных подписей произвести промежуточное сохранение хранилища и удаление подписей
            CancellationToken token = _cts.Token;
            Channel<string> channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>();
            ChannelWriter<string> deleteQueue = channel.Writer;
            Task deleteTask = DeleteWorkerAsync(channel.Reader, token);
            object saveSync = new object();
            int maxJobs = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2;
            using SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new(maxJobs);
            try
            {
                foreach (string path in signatures)
                {
                    await semaphore.WaitAsync(token);
                    if (tasks.Count > maxJobs * 2)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Count; i++) // не позволит списку тасков расти бесконечно
                        {
                            if (tasks[i].IsCompletedSuccessfully)
                            {
                                tasks.RemoveAt(i--);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                            if (UploadSigningCerts(mainStore, path, importStats) && configuration.NeedCleaning)
                            {
                                deleteQueue.TryWrite(path);
                            }
                            bool needSave = false;
                            lock (saveSync)
                            {
                                if (++processedSignatures > proccessedForSave * saveIndex)
                                {
                                    saveIndex++;
                                    needSave = true;
                                }
                            }
                            if (needSave)
                            {
                                LogsHelper.WriteEventLog("Промежуточное сохранение хранилища сертификатов...");
                                mainStore.WriteIfChanged();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) when (e is not OperationCanceledException)
                        {
                            LogsHelper.WriteLog("SignatureImportService/ImportSigningCerts:Task.Factory.StartNew", e);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            semaphore.Release();
                        }
                    }, token));
                }
                        
                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                mainStore.WriteIfChanged();
                deleteQueue.Complete();
                await deleteTask;
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) { }

            string result = (token.IsCancellationRequested ? cancelMsg : endMsg) + $"Certificates found: {importStats.all}. Was imported: {importStats.imported}." + (importStats.parsingFailed > 0 ? $" Unrecognized files: {importStats.parsingFailed}" : "");
            LogsHelper.WriteEventLog(result);

            return new ImportSigningCertsResult(result, token.IsCancellationRequested);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        _cts = null;
    }
}

private bool UploadSigningCerts(Store store, string path, ImportStats importStats)
{
    bool toBeDeleted = true;
    CryptoClient client = CryptoServiceContext.DefaultInstance.CryptoClient;

    try
    {
        CertInfo[] certs = client.GetSignCmsInfo(File.ReadAllBytes(path)).Certs.ToArray(); // здесь непонятно, что такое за коллекция Certs и зачем ее клонировать

        Interlocked.Add(ref importStats.all, certs.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < certs.Length; i++)
        {

        }
        return toBeDeleted;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogsHelper.WriteLog("SignatureImportService/UploadSigningCerts", e);
        LogsHelper.WriteEventLog($"Ошибка импорта сертификата из подписи: {Path.GetFileName(path)};");
        Interlocked.Increment(ref importStats.errors);
        return false;
    }
}

private async Task DeleteWorkerAsync(ChannelReader<string> reader, CancellationToken token)
{
    await foreach (string path in reader.ReadAllAsync(token))
    {
        try
        {
            File.Delete(path); // если файловая система медленная, здесь можно await Task.Run(() => File.Delete(path));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogsHelper.WriteLog("ImportResult/DeleteSignatures", e);
        }
    }
}
```

`bool` переменные тоже бессмысленные, у вас есть потокобезопасный CTS, его и используйте, например так

```
public bool WasCancelled => _cts?.IsCancellationRequested ?? false;
public bool IsWorking => !_cts?.IsCancellationRequested ?? false;

private CancellationTokenSource _cts;
```

Избавляйтесь от статики дальше. И отвыкайте от списков в пользу массивов, если не надо динамически добавлять и удалять элементы из списка. Массивы легче и работают быстрее.

Вот еще почитайте в тему: [c# как ускорить добавление потоков используя async-await](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1535648/373567)

Comment: В конструкции `if (processedSignatures > proccessedForSave * saveIndex)` без лока разве не может получиться так, что несколько потоков "залезут" в этот условный блок и получим множественное сохранение и инкремент индекса `saveIndex`?

Comment: @Dany поставил инкремент повыше. Так как потоков не много вероятность критически мала, но имеется, вы правы. С локом хуже получится. +Добавил проверочку в начало метода.

Comment: @Dany ок, уговорили, переписал на полностью потокобезопасный код, но само сохранение все равно за пределами лока.

Comment: Вы написали, что следует избавиться от статики - в чём причина? Если мне нужно получать какую-то информацию о данном классе в разных методах контроллера, статистику, то лучше реализовать класс как singleton, чем делать необходимые мне поля статическими?

Comment: @Dany вы пишете сервер, так? Сервер должен уметь обслуживать сколько угодно запросов одновременно, так? О какой статике может быть речь? Не закладывайте в архитектуру ни статику, не синглтоны. Как я понял, ответ не помог?

Comment: Нет, всё отлично. Спасибо)