# Как реализовать Producer/consumer паттерн для web-scraper'а с корректным завершением

Tags: c#, многопоточность, синхронизация, web-scraping, распараллеливание

Хочу сделать свой web-scraper многопоточным.

В работе scraper'а используется две коллекции - посещенных ссылок и очередь ссылок для обработки.
По ссылкам хожу через Selenium ChromeDriver, а чтобы распараллелить ChromeDriver - нужно работать через потоки, с Task'ами рабочих подходов не встретил.

По сути имеем producer/consumer, где несколько producer/consumer'ов в одном лице со следующими ограничениями:

- Нельзя плодить экземпляры браузера в безлимитном режиме (память)
- Нужно переиспользовать экземпляры, выделенные потоку повторно (долгая инициализация)

И казалось бы, тут очевидное решение - сделать несколько Thread'ов c общими коллекциями посещенных и не посещенных ссылок и «дело в шляпе»‎, и пусть каждый поток работает до тех пор, пока в очереди что-то есть.

Но может возникнуть следующая неприятная ситуация. **К примеру, есть 8 экземпляров браузера, в 8 потоках «гуляющие по сети».

И вот, в какой-то момент, очередь ссылок стала пуста, 1 поток все еще работает над текущей страницей, а остальные 7 поглядели, что обрабатывать им нечего и завершились.

И тут первый поток добавляет в очередь 10000 ссылок (всякое бывает), с которыми он вынужден разгребаться до скончания времен.**

В теории возникает 4 ситуации:

| Очередь ссылок | Другие потоки | Ожидаемое поведение текущего потока |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Есть ссылки | Есть работающие | Взять следующую ссылку из очереди |
| Есть ссылки | Есть ожидающие ссылок | Взять следующую ссылку из очереди |
| Пустая | Есть работающие | Перейти к ожиданию результатов других потоков |
| Пустая | Есть ожидающие ссылок | Завершить работу |

И вопрос мой заключается в том, как реализовать описанное в третьем пункте ожидание, чтобы, грубо говоря:

- Если очередь ссылок пуста, но есть потоки «в работе» - текущий поток должен ожидать изменения «статуса» любого из потоков.
- Как только какой-либо из соседей закончил текущую итерацию работы, повторить проверку.
- **И только в случае, если все потоки «ждут», они должны завершиться.**

В таком случае, потоки завершатся все разом и именно в тот момент, когда гарантированно не будет новых ссылок.

Вопрос - как?

Однопоточный код у меня примерно такого плана:

```
var unvisitedLinks = new ConcurrentQueue<IUrl>(startUrls);
var visitedLinks = new BlockingCollection<IUrl>();

while (unvisitedLinks.TryDequeue(out var currentUrl))
{
    // Проверяем, что не посещали ссылку
    if (visitedLinks.Any(link => link == currentUrl)) continue;

    Navigate(currentUrl);

    // Извлечение информации
    var scrapedObjects = ScrapeObjects(currentUrl, otherParams);

    foreach (var scrapedObject in scrapedObjects)
    {
        if (scrapedObject is IUrl url) unvisitedLinks.Enqueue(url);

        if (scrapedObject is IScrapingResult item) yield return item;
    }

    // Добавляем ссылку в посещенные
    visitedLinks.Add(currentUrl);

    // Делаем паузу
    await Task.Delay(delay);
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567

Comment: Вы просто не освоили `BlockingCollection`, пример по ссылке в синем блоке в самом верху. Дополнительная очередь здесь не нужна, совсем.

Comment: @aepot, да, полностью с вами согласен, `BlockingCollection` решает задачу "усыпления" потоков, которые ждут данных, поясните только, какой должен быть код, чтобы завершить все потоки, работающие с ней. В произвольном потоке я не могу вызвать CompleteAdding, т.к. он не знает, положат ли в коллекцию что-то другие потоки.

Comment: @aepot у меня в оригинальном коде всего 2 коллекции, посещенных и непосещенных ссылок. Повторюсь, т.к. это web-scraper, то каждый worker, грубо говоря, заходит на страницу, собирает нужные ему данные и ссылки, и кладет их в очередь обработки. Т.е. он сам себе и своим соседям producer, а ссылки могут быть собраны дважды. Поэтому нужно исключить повторное их посещение. Для этого и существует дополнительная коллекция.

Comment: Перефразирую вопрос. Пусть у меня N потоков, обрабатывающих коллекцию. Можно ли вызвать `BlockingCollection.CompleteAdding` в N+1 потоке, но только в том случае, если все N потоков-обработчиков находятся в состоянии блокировки?

Comment: _чтобы завершить все потоки, работающие с ней_ - просто отправляете `.CompleteAdding()` и все циклы завершаются. Вызвать для отдельного потока не получится, только для всех сразу. CompleteAdding сообщает всем, что данных больше не будет, происходит нормальное завершение цикла `foreach`. Вызов можно делать из какого угодно потока, как и добавлять элементы, `BlockingCollection` полностью потокобезопасна.

Comment: @aepot корректным ли решением будет завести отдельный управляющий поток, который будет 
 периодически просыпаться, и если все потоки имеют состояние `ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin`, а в коллекции не будет элементов, то он будет вызывать `.CompleteAdding()`?

Comment: Зачем? Вы добавляете в коллекцию элементы, так? Вы решаете, когда закончите добавление, так? Ну вот как закончили добаление, совсем, окончательно, так и вызывайте `CompleteAdding`, все воркеры завершатся. Не вижу никакого смысла перезапускать воркеры когда добавление не окончено, пусть висят себе, ждут. А так, вы знаете, как запустить всё с нуля, как полностью все остановить, что мешает использовать эти приёмы когда нужно? Вызов `CompleteAdding` не останавливает ничего сразу, завершение произойдет именно тогда, когда всё будет обработано полностью, и коллекция будет пустая. Протестируйте.

Comment: @aepot, ну вот еще раз приведу вам пример. Работает 8 потоков по простому алгоритму: взять ссылку из `BlockingCollection bc`, пройти по ссылке браузером и собрать новые ссылки. Свежесобранные ссылки добавляются в `bc`. Ни один из потоков не знает, закончили ли другие своё добавление, т.е. ни один не имеет права вызвать `.CompleteAdding`. В итоге все рано или поздно повиснут в `foreach (var url in bc.GetConsumingEnumerable()) {/* */}`. А гарантия, что все ссылки добавлены возникает как раз только в тот момент, когда `bc.Count == 0` и ни один из потоков "не гуляет по вебу" в поисках ссылок.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141605/discussion-between-mainefremov-and-aepot).

Comment: Вы добавляете ссылки, где работать, случайный поток из запущенных забирает ссылку и начинает работать. Ему незачем знать, что там в других потоках происходит. Кто добавляет ссылки, то есть запускает весь процесс, тот и отвечает за окончание работы. Если у вас запросы на добавлени из самих воркеров валятся, то у вас проблемы с архитектурой приложения, такого не должно быть. Вы можете создать вторую коллекцию, которая обрабатывает ответы воркеров, то есть если надо продолжить парсить, то воркер возвращает обработчик ответ, в котором есть ссылки для продолжения работы, обработчик их закидывает...

Comment: ...в очередь. Работа будет считаться завершенной, когда количество ответов = количеству отправленных ссылок в работу и новых ссылок нет. Но не сам воркер должен это считать, этим должен заниматься один управляющий поток-обработчик. Воркер должен быть супертупой и легковесный,  выполнять свою узкую задачу, какую именно - определите сами, но хвост собакой вилять не должен. Подумайте над архитектурой, задача очень простая.

Comment: @aepot пока что нашел решение через `WaitHanle.WaitAll`, в комментарий, к сожалению, не влезает, а вопрос закрыт как дубль. Разместил [тут](https://pastebin.com/nPFzAvai).

Comment: Ссылка в самом первом комментарии мимо прошла? Я ж не просто так вам ее дал. Изобретаете велосипед. Есть же асинхронное программирование и `Task`, и комбинаторы для ожидания. А вы голые потоки теребите. `BlockingCollection`, это тоже как бы устаревший инструмент.