# Можно ли внутри Semaphore использовать lock?

Tags: c#

Я написал следующий код:

```
public class WorkerQueue<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> _resource = new();

    private readonly Semaphore _semaphore = new(5, 10);

    public void AddItem(T item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Поток {Thread.CurrentThread.Name} готов добавить элемент");

        _semaphore.WaitOne();

        try
        {
            lock (_resource)
            {
                _resource.Add(item);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Поток {Thread.CurrentThread.Name} добавил элемент");
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    public int GetCountItems()
    {
        return _resource.Count();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetItems()
    {
        return _resource.OrderBy(x=>x);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    private static List<Thread> _threads = new();

    private static WorkerQueue<int> _worker = new();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            Thread thread = new(ThreadProc);

            thread.Name = i.ToString();

            thread.Start();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

        int count = _worker.GetCountItems();

        var items = _worker.GetItems().GroupBy(x=>x)
            .Select(x=> new
            {
                Key = x.Key,
                Count =  x.Count()
            }).Where(x=> x.Count != 6);
    }

    private static void ThreadProc()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            _worker.AddItem(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Я здесь использую lock так как внутри Semaphore к моему ресурсу будет одновременно обращаться 5 потоков, что приведёт к тому, что у меня в списке будут неполные данные. Но есть подозрения, что тогда тут Semaphore и не нужен вообще)

Comment: Такие же подозрения, смысл в семафоре, если в итоге все равно lock?

Comment: `GetCountItems()` должно быть под локом, `GetItems()` - под лок и снапшотом возвращать. В противном случае, с семафором, локом или без, этот код нельзя назвать потокобезопасным. `return _resource.Count();` можно оптимизировать - `return _resource.Count;`

Comment: вообще, тут больше вопросов, чем ответов. Например, зачем вам lock вообще, почему бы не использовать ConcurrentBag и е париться о конкурентном доступе. Ну и почему класс называется Queue, но там только добавление, а извлечения из очерези нет? Но я так понял, это учебный пример, для учебного это ок конечно, чисто поиграть с многопоточностью.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567 вот немного примеров использования семафора

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Semaphore` ограничивает число **одновременных** заходов в блок кода, поэтому он может являться заменой `lock` только в том случае, если семафор настроен ровно на 1 заход. А если он настроен, скажем, на 5 **одновременных** заходов, то такой код не будет потокобезопасным, нужно применять `lock` или использовать потокобезопасные коллекции.

И да, под `lock` возможно нужно помещать не только добавление в список, но и какие-то обращения к нему, тут я точно не скажу, лучше посмотреть какую-нибудь готовую реализацию потокобезопасного списка на эту тему или прочитать в документации, какие обращения к этой коллекции являются потокобезопасными, а какие нет.

И ещё - всегда выделяйте для `lock` **отдельный простой объект `object`**, обычно его так и называют `lockObject`, никогда не делайте `lock` на сложные объекты (например, коллекции), и те объекты, которые вы используете в своём коде каким-то другим образом. Это может привести к нехорошим последствиям. Объяснения можно прочитать в документации, но проще запомнить - для `lock` используйте отдельный приватный `object`, специально выделенный для этой цели.

Вообще `Semaphore` используется не для создания потокобезопасного кода, а чтобы создать "бутылочное горлышко", не позволяющее блоку кода одновременно обрабатывать слишком много запросов. Это может быть нужно по разным причинам. Например, если у вас есть код, который очень сильно потребляет ресурсы: CPU, память, сеть, БД, и есть вероятность, что в этот фрагмент кода попадёт одновременно много запросов, то у вас просто не хватит ресурсов, чтобы это всё разгрести одновременно (например, кончится память на сервере и программа просто упадёт), либо код будет просто не оптимально работать (своппинг, "драка" за CPU, блокировки БД) - вот тогда можно использовать `Semaphore`.

И ещё сейчас чаще используют [SemaphoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=net-7.0), он более легковесный.

В целом семафор полезен, например, для кода, разгребающего некую очередь - чтобы чётко ограничить в ресурсах обработчик очереди.

P.S. Да, конкретно в вашем случае семафор вообще бесполезен, конечно, всё-равно всё упрётся в `lock`. Но если бы в вашем коде было что-то ещё, а `lock` ограничивал бы только небольшие части вашего кода, тогда в нём, возможно, был бы смысл.

Comment: _lockObject_ - `syncRoot`?

Comment: @aepot Да без разницы в общем как называть по большому счёту то.

Comment: @aepot тоже всегда называл lockObject :)
Имхо, но тут дело вкуса)

Comment: @LiptonDev это из разряда `List<User> usersList`, читать полезную книжку Роберт Мартин "Чистый код".