# Почему Task начинает работу только после запуска всего List<Task>?

Tags: c#, async-await

Сабж. Помогите разобраться в этой магии.
Есть такой класс.

```cs
public class ParserV2 
{
    private static SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(3);
    private static  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    private Domain domain;

    static ParserV2()
    {
     //Устанавливаем Заголовки
    }
    private async Task GetDomainAsync(){//Делаем GET запрос к апи}
    private async Task CheckDomainAsync(){//Делаем проверку}
    private async Task<string> UpdateBdDomainAsync(){//Делаем PUT запрос к апи}
       //Метод которым запускаем все действия которые выше    
    public async Task Check(CancellationToken token) 
    {
        if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            
            semaphore.Wait();
           
        do
        {     
                await GetDomainAsync();         
        }
        while (domain == null);

        do
        {
            await CheckDomainAsync();
        }
        while (domain.CMS == null);


        while(true) 
        {
            var code = await UpdateBdDomainAsync();
            if (code =="OK") 
            {
                break;      
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Поток освобожден");
        semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

`Main` у меня такой

```cs
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
List <ParserV2> parse = new List <ParserV2> ();

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
{
  parse.Add(new ParserV2());
}

List <Task> tasksParse = new List <Task> ();

foreach(var t in parse) 
{
  tasksParse.Add(new Task(() => t.Check(cts.Token)));
}

foreach (var t in tasksParse)
{
 t.Start();
}
```

Проблема в том что задачи начинают выполнятся только после того как в  `foreach` всем сделает `t.Start();`
Я думал что таски которые я запускаю сразу будут выполнятся но это не так.
Как мне запускать таски по мере их запуска а не все сразу?

Comment: Таски стартуют не сразу, не моментально. Ващ foreach сильно быстрый, потому таски не успевают стартануть до того, как он закончится. Добавьте в foreach задержку типа `Thread.Sleep(10000)` и увидите, что таски начинают колупаться до того, как цикл кончится.

Comment: С ожиданием в 10 секунд теряется весь смысл.

Comment: я не предлагаю вам это ожидание оставить - вы же хотели узнать как стартуют таски? С задержкой вы увидите, что таски стартуют не сразу. Как убедитесь - задержку удалите

Comment: `таски которые я запускаю сразу будут выполнятся но это не так` это действительно не так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка: `semaphore.Wait();` замените на `await semaphore.WaitAsync();` и все заработает как надо.

Не используйте конструктор `new Task`, вообще никогда, используйте `Task.Run`, тогда таски будут стартовать сразу. `tasksParse.Add(Task.Run(() => t.Check(cts.Token)));` - а второй цикл со `.Start()` не нужен.

Хотя, это же асинхронный метод, ему вообще не нужен `Task.Run`. Вот так надо.

```
tasksParse.Add(t.Check(cts.Token));
```

Вот ещё интересное, поразбирайтесь: [Массовые асинхронные вызовы с ограничением на количество параллельных без семафора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567)

Comment: Ха, а слона то я и не заметил 

Comment: @tym32167 я тоже одного не сразу заметил, дописал

Comment: Спасибо попробую, пока уже почти переписал на на меньшее количество тасков но которые будут по кругу работать.

Comment: @User12351259599491 вы используете потоки поверх асинхронной операции, масло масляное. Зачем выделять поток под то, что потоки по своей природе не занимает? :) Незачем. И `await Task.WhenAll(tasksParse)` не забудьте чтобы дождаться конца работы операций.

Comment: Я делаю по наитию) И как то сложно понимаю(не понимаю)  и await/async можно сказать наугад ставлю

Comment: @User12351259599491 тогда просто воспользуйтесь советами.

Comment: Что значит "вы используете потоки поверх асинхронной операции"?  await/async используют же вместе с  Task

Comment: @User12351259599491 `new Task().Start()` или `Task.Run` стартуют поток, при этом вы заворачиваете в поток метод, который и так сам по себе возвращает `Task`, то есть кладете `Task` внутрь `Task`. Это бессмысленно. Явный запуск потока через `Task.Run` больше подходит для синхронных длительных операций, а не для асинхронных.