# Почему методы Parallel.For/Foreach не работают с асинхронной лямбдой?

Tags: c#

Есть следующий кусок кода:

```
private static void WorkAsync()
{
    Parallel.For(0,
        20,
         async i =>
         {
             await Task.Delay(50000);
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        });
}
```

При вызове метода WorkAsync, он практически сразу возвращает управление вызывающему коду, хотя цикл For ещё не завершился. Я правильно понимаю, что асинхронная лямбда при каждом вызове возвращает управление вызывающему потоку и поэтому не происходит ожидание?

Comment: Да. Поэтому в дотнет 6+ наконец-то сделали `Parallel.ForEachAsync`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша лямбда это `async void`, а `async void` невозможно ожидать.

Для асинхронных вызовов можно не использовать `Parallel`. Тем более у `Parallel.For` блокирующее синхронное ожидание, что для асинхронной среды не хорошо.

Как-то так это делается:

```
private static async Task WorkAsync()
{
    List<Task> tasks = new();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(JobAsync(i));
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private static async Task JobAsync(int i)
{
    await Task.Delay(50000);
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Вызов выглядит так:

```
await WorkAsync();
```

---

Если очень хочется, можно через лямбду:

```
private static async Task WorkAsync()
{
    List<Task> tasks = new();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(((Func<int, Task>)(async index =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(50000);
            Console.WriteLine(index);
        }))(i));
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Или так:

```
private static async Task WorkAsync()
{
    List<Task> tasks = new();
    Func<int, Task> func = async index =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(50000);
        Console.WriteLine(index);
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(func(i));
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Можно даже с ограничением на количество одновременно выполняемых задач: [Массовые асинхронные вызовы с ограничением на количество параллельных без семафора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567)