# Асинхронные http-запросы

Tags: c#, .net, http, асинхронность

Я хочу реализовать специальный http-клиент, который будет накладывать ограничение на отправку запросов (например, запрос можно делать не чаще, чем раз в секунду). Я написал следующий код:

```
public class SmartClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private static DateTime? _lastRequest = null;

    public SmartClient()
    {
        _client = new();
    }

    public async Task<string> Get(string url)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (_lastRequest != null && _lastRequest.Value.AddSeconds(1) > DateTime.Now)
            {
                await Task.Delay(100);
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }

        _lastRequest = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine($"Request: {url}");
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
        var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Далее я инициализирую 10 объектов `SmartClient`, создаю на каждый по одной таске `.Get()` и помещаю все задачи в один список. Потом вызываю `await Tasks.WaitAll(tasks);` и жду, что все мои запросы выполнятся в течение 10 секунд. Но на практике получаю несколько одновременных запусков по несколько запросов за раз. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Как по вашему один объект SmartClient должен знать про лимит другого SmartClient? SmartClient должен быть один

Comment: В моем понимании каждая задача должна выжидать момент, когда не выполнится условие. А дальше пойдет выставит время последнего запроса и пойдет его выполнять. Раз только одна случайная задача дожидается момента и сразу обновляет ```_lastRequest```, то мне казалось, что они отработают по очереди. ```_lastRequest``` - статическое поле, общее для всех задач, так что какая разница сколько создается клиентов?

Comment: Оставим вопрос что создавать много HttpClient не рекомендуется и что есть более адекватные методы синхронизации и сразу в суть - у вас типичная гонка потоков, потому что работа с _lastRequest никак не синхронизируется. В общих чертах: 1 заход - все 10 клиентов увидели что _lastRequest== null и сразу пошли к break. 2 и все прочие заходы - все прочитали _lastRequest подождали секунду и снова все ломанулись на выход.

Comment: На .net по дефолту асинхронные задачи запускаются в многопоточном режиме?

Comment: Все ЗАВИСИТ от типа создания таски. Но мало кто создает таски вручную (вот их нужно запускать ручками), а обычно получают их как результат вызова метода. А это значит что они планируются на выполнение в текущем контексте синхронизации, а без контекста это пул потоков. А там. если есть свободные потоки, то выполнение наступит сразу. Ну и сразу скажу - решение "обернем все в lock" является плохим решением. Будет бодание и ситуация что второй запрос постоянно будет ждать своей очереди, а остальные влезать пока он спит.

Comment: У меня даже с lock не работает) Я использую его в проверке условий на ```_lastRequest``` и там, где этот самый ```_lastRequest``` обновляется. Результат тот же самый

Comment: Не работает потому что lock и await не могут работать вместе. А lock должен быть обернут сразу и над проверкой и над присвоением нового времени - то есть 1 штука. Вам тут поможет семафор со значением 1 (он из коробки имеет асинк методы). Только не просто "обернуть все" конечно иначе `await Task.Delay(100)` будет удерживать от семафор от релиза

Comment: Я делаю так: создаю bool-переменную needWait, затем в lock присваиваю ей значение и после конца блока lock идет if

Comment: В асинхронном контексте не долдно быть никаких синхронных lock. Отредактируйте вопрос, опишите цель задачи и покажите вызывающий код. Пока ясно только то что клиент должен быть всего один.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567

Comment: `HttpClient` очень хорошо дополняется без всяких оберток/декораторов, делается это все при помощи простых `Handler` классов. В документации есть отличный пример реализации ["лимитера"](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/extensions/http-ratelimiter), который если немного дописать, получите нужный вам результат. А пока, как вам и сказали выше, у вас должен быть один экземпляр клиента и правильно созданные "Таски", чтоб все работало так, как вы ожидаете, а еще лучше семафор, а еще лучше очередь.

Comment: Давайте я поставлю задачу так. У меня есть много тасок, каждая из которых делает что-то... Я хочу ограничить промежутки между их запусками, например, одной секундой. Каждая таска может выполняться хоть намного меньше секунды, хоть намного больше, главное, чтобы 10 тасок асинхронно запустились в течение ~10 секунд (то есть не существовало такого временного промежутка длиной 1 секунду, в котором бы запустилось одновременно 2 задачи). А после запуска они могут выполняться как угодно, к примеру если каждая таска выполняется 10 секунд, 10 задач должны отработать условно за 19 секунд